# Simbolo externo sin resolver ¿Qué he hecho mal?

Tags: c++, enlazado

Llevo un buen rato intentando resolver un problema, he intentado resolverlo con diferentes compiladores y no hay manera. El programa es más complejo pero he podido resumirlo en el siguiente código:

`S.hpp`

```
#ifndef S_HPP
#define S_HPP

struct S
{
    int uno();
    int dos();
};

#endif
```

`S.cpp`

```
#include "S.hpp"

int S::uno() { return 1; }
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include "S.hpp"

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    S s;

    std::cout << s.uno() + s.dos() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Los errores que tengo son los siguientes:

`GCC HEAD 8.0.0 201704`

> ```
> /tmp/ccRBiKEw.o: In function `main':
> prog.cc:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `S::dos()'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> ```

`clang HEAD 5.0.0`

> ```
> /tmp/prog-8f7223.o: In function `main':
> prog.cc:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `S::dos()'
> clang-5.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> ```

¿Alguien me puede decir qué está fallando?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

#### Problema.

Se trata de un problema habitual en *C++*, que normalmente pasa desapercibido en códigos mucho más complejos pero en tu caso es muy fácil de localizar:

Te falta la definición de la función `S::dos`

#### Solución.

Añade esta línea en `S.cpp`:

```
int S::dos() { lo que toque... }
```

#### Explicación.

El [enlazador](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enlazador) no ha sido capaz de encontrar la [Unidad de Traducción [image]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) en que la función `S::dos` estaba definida, y al intentar generar el [programa](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ejecutable) final ha fallado porque le faltaba una de las piezas necesarias.

Para entender esto, debemos conocer el concepto de *Unidad de Traducción*.

#### Unidad de Traducción (UdT).

Una *UdT* es, a grandes rasgos el resultado intermedio de procesar y compilar un archivo de código. Es decir: el [preprocesador](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprocesador) ha realizado sus tareas (incluir cabeceras `#include`, expandir macros `#define`, descartar código en compilación condicional `#ifdef`, `#else`, `#endif`) y el compilador ha realizado una compilación con el archivo resultante, dicha compilación va a parar a un [archivo objeto [image]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) y el enlazado entre archivos objetos es lo que acaba generando el [programa](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ejecutable) final.

Dado que una *UdT* contiene el resultado de compilar código, sólo generarán archivos objeto aquellos archivos de código que contengan código compilable; En otras palabras un archivo de código que tan sólo contenga declaraciones (por ejemplo una cabecera `.h` o `.hpp`<sup>1</sup>) no generará archivo objeto ni consistirá en una *UdT* pero un archivo de código con definiciones (por ejemplo un archivo `.c` o `.cpp`<sup>1</sup>) será una UdT y generará un archivo objeto.

Cada *UdT* dispondrá de las entidades (objetos, funciones, enumerados) que hayan sido compiladas en su archivo de objeto:
[image]

En este ejemplo el objeto `S` tiene dos funciones (`S::uno` y `S::dos`) que son compiladas y van a parar al archivo objeto `S.obj` que es la representación binaria de la *UdT* de `S.cpp`. Si en algún otro punto del programa se requiere el uso de un objeto de tipo `S` (porque alguien ha incluido `S.hpp` y ha usado alguna de sus funciones) el [enlazador](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enlazador) buscará el archivo objeto que contenga estas funciones y lo usará para crear el programa final. Las definiciones de un objeto no tienen por qué estar en un sólo archivo de código, pueden estar dispersas en otros archivos y cada uno de ellos creará su *UdT*:
[image]

Será el enlazador el que se encargue después de juntar todas las piezas para crear el programa, pero si entre todos los archivos objeto disponibles para el enlazador, no se encuentra alguna de las definiciones requeridas se provocará un fallo de enlazado como el que has experimentado:
[image]

---

<sup>1</sup>La extensión del archivo es irrelevante, lo importante es el contenido del archivo.

Comment: ¿De donde has sacado los diagramas? D:

Comment: Están hechos con Google drawings.

Comment: +1 - Excelente explicación.

Comment: ¡Qué gustazo de respuesta! Muchas gracias

Comment: No será: "no ha sido capaz"?

Comment: @Mateo ¿A qué te refieres?

Comment: Justo debajo de la explicación. *El enlazador no ha sido incapaz de encontrar la Unidad de Traducción  en que la función S::dos estaba definida,*

Comment: @Mateo Corregido ¡Gracias!.