# Mandar una variable QSerialPort a otro archivo

Tags: c++, qt

Actualmente estoy programando una app en C++ con IDE Qt pero necesito mandar una variable QSerialPort a otro archivo .cpp para poder tener la conexión en cualquier pantalla de la aplicación pero no me acepta la variable y quisiera saber si solo las variables de tipo Int, float, String, etc... se pueden jalar o se puede hacer con cualquier tipo de variable

Dejo el código que utilizo:
Principal.h

```
#ifndef PRINCIPAL_H
#define PRINCIPAL_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QSerialPort>

namespace Ui {
class Principal;
}

class Principal : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Principal(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Principal();

    QSerialPort Puerto;
private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();

    void on_PruebaCon_clicked();
private:
    Ui::Principal *ui;
};

#endif // PRINCIPAL_H
```

Principal.cpp

```
#include "principal.h"
#include "ui_principal.h"
#include <puertoserial.h>
#include <conectados.h>
#include <serialport.h>
#include <QDebug>

Principal::Principal(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Principal)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    Puerto.setPortName("/dev/ttyUSB0");
    if(Puerto.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)){
        Puerto.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);
        Puerto.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
        Puerto.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
        Puerto.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
        Puerto.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
        qDebug() << "Conectado a puerto " << Puerto.portName() << " Conexión Original";
    }else{
        qDebug() << Puerto.errorString();
    }
}

Principal::~Principal()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Principal::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    PuertoSerial *U = new PuertoSerial();
    U->show();
}

void Principal::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    ConectaDos *D = new ConectaDos();
    D->show();
}

void Principal::on_PruebaCon_clicked()
{
    if(Puerto.isOpen()){
        ui->Estado->setText("Conectado a puerto: " + Puerto.portName());
    }else{
        ui->Estado->setText("Error! " + Puerto.errorString());
    }
}
```

conectados.h

```
#ifndef CONECTADOS_H
#define CONECTADOS_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <principal.h>
#include <serialport.h>
#include <QSerialPort>

extern QSerialPort Puerto;
namespace Ui {
class ConectaDos;
}

class ConectaDos : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ConectaDos(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~ConectaDos();

    SerialPort *ConnectDos;
private slots:
    void on_EnviarDatos_clicked();

    void on_CambiaVentana_clicked();

    void on_ProbConDos_clicked();
private:
    Ui::ConectaDos *ui;
};

#endif // CONECTADOS_H
```

conectados.cpp

```
#include "conectados.h"
#include "ui_conectados.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <puertoserial.h>
#include <principal.h>

ConectaDos::ConectaDos(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ConectaDos)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

ConectaDos::~ConectaDos()
{
    delete ui;
}

void ConectaDos::on_EnviarDatos_clicked()
{

}

void ConectaDos::on_CambiaVentana_clicked()
{
    PuertoSerial *Uno = new PuertoSerial();
    Uno->show();
    this->close();
}

void ConectaDos::on_ProbConDos_clicked()
{
    QSerialPort Puerto;
    if(Puerto.isOpen()){
        ui->EstadoCD->setText("Puerto abierto " + Puerto.portName() + "Segunda Conexión");
    }else{
        ui->EstadoCD->setText("Error! " + Puerto.errorString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Esta interesante la pregunta. 

Pregunta: ¿en el constructor de Principal no puedes llamar al constructor de ConectaDos y pasarla variable por referencia?

Comment: Pones el código pero... no pones qué error recibes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Si se puede.

> **Necesito mandar una variable QSerialPort a otro archivo .cpp**

Esto no tiene ningún sentido, las variables no se envían entre archivos. Seguramente estás hablando de [Unidades de Traducción](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/65557/simbolo-externo-sin-resolver-qu%c3%a9-he-hecho-mal).

> Quisiera saber si sólo las variables de tipo Int, float, String, etc... se pueden jalar o se puede hacer con cualquier tipo de variable.

Asumiendo que te refieras a si cualquier instancia de cualquier tipo de datos se puede usar como dato externo, la respuesta es: Si.

#### Enlazar.

Las variables externas se enlazan en la fase de enlazado, esto es: cuando los objetos binarios (normalmente de extensión .obj) de las Unidades de Traducción han sido ya generados. Para que una variable externa sea enlazada, tienes que **declararla** como `extern` en todos los sitios que la quieras usar y **definirla** en solo uno sitio **omitiendo el declarador `extern`**, así pues:

`Archivo1.cpp`

```
extern MiClase mi_clase;
```

`Archivo2.cpp`

```
extern MiClase mi_clase;
```

`Archivo3.cpp`

```
extern MiClase mi_clase;
```

Con estas declaraciones le estamos diciendo al compilador "*eh, en otra Unidad de Traducción está definido un objeto de tipo `MiClase` llamado `mi_clase`*", es decir: hemos **declarado** la existencia de `mi_clase`. En otro archivo:

`Archivo0.cpp`

```
MiClase mi_clase;
```

Aquí le estamos diciendo al compilador "*oye, crea un un objeto de tipo `MiClase` llamado `mi_clase` en esta Unidad de Traducción*". Fíjate que `mi_clase` de `Archivo0.cpp` no tiene ni idea de estar siendo referenciado desde otros tres archivos. Si olvidases la definición de `mi_clase` la generación del archivo ejecutable fallaría en tiempo de [enlazado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enlazado) con un error de "[Símbolo externo sin resolver](https://www.google.es/search?q=simbolo+externo+sin+resolver)".

#### Tu problema.

No me queda claro tu problema porque olvidaste añadir a tu pregunta el error que genera tu código, pero observo que tienes una variable declarada como externa:

`conectados.h`

```
extern QSerialPort Puerto;
```

Le estás diciendo al compilador "*eh, en otra Unidad de Traducción está definido un objeto de tipo `QSerialPort` llamado `Puerto`*", pero según veo en el código que has publicado, le estás mintiendo al compilador:

`Principal.h`

```
class Principal : public QWidget
{
    // ...

    QSerialPort Puerto;

    // ...
};
```

Aquí le dices al compilador "*hey, te voy a describir cómo es el objeto de tipo `Principal`, entre otras cosas este objeto tiene un miembro de tipo `QSerialPort` llamado `Puerto`*". Así que el objeto `QSerialPort Principal::Puerto` no puede ser la definición de `extern QSerialPort Puerto`.

`conectados.cpp`

```
void ConectaDos::on_ProbConDos_clicked()
{
    QSerialPort Puerto;

    // ...
}
```

Aquí le dices al compilador "*oye ¿recuerdas que te dije que el tipo `ConectaDos` tenía una función llamada `on_ProbConDos_clicked()`? pues te voy a decir lo que esta función hace; lo primero que hace es crear un objeto de tipo `QSerialPort` llamado `Puerto`*". Así que el objeto `QSerialPort Puerto` sólo visible dentro de la función `ConectaDos::on_ProbConDos_clicked()` no puede ser la definición de `extern QSerialPort Puerto`.

Y por lo tanto, el código seguramente te falla al enlazar... a no ser que tengas más código que no nos hayas mostrado.

Comment: ¿Y como haría para decirle que `QSerialPort Puerto;` es de una definición `extern`?

Comment: Hola PaperBirdMaster, es todo el código, de hecho hice este proyecto solo para pruebas ya que en el que estoy desarrollando ya tengo bastante código, y lo que necesito es que al **abrir la conexión en el archivo principal pueda usar esa misma conexión en consultados.cpp** y no salta ningún error **pero al intentar "probar la conexión" en consultados no abre el puerto**, **es como si estuviera cerrado o no disponible.**

Comment: Puedo mandarles todo el proyecto de prueba si quieren, ahorita opté por abrir 2 puertos en el proyecto que estoy haciendo, pero si me interesa resolver este problema para en un futuro implementar la conexión con un solo puerto.

Comment: Ya has declarado `QSerialPort Puerto;` como `extern`, no entiendo tu pregunta.

Comment: Si, pero aunque esté declarado como extern, ya sea al inicio del archivo ´conectados.cpp´ o en la función ´void ConectaDos::on_ProbConDos_clicked()´, no puedo establecer conexión con el puerto serial que la variable abre cuando le establezco los parametros en ´principal.cpp´

Comment: @AarónGutiérrez tal y como expongo en la respuesta (tal vez no con la suficiente claridad) los `QSerialPort` dentro de `class Principal` y `void ConectaDos::on_ProbConDos_clicked()´ no hacen referencia a la misma instancia de `QSerialPort` que `extern QSerialPort Puerto` de conectados.h.

Comment: Si vi eso, lo verificaré cuando acabe con unas cosas del proyecto y creo haber entendido lo que dijiste y me sentí como un verdadero tonto cuando lo mencionaste, marcaré tu respuesta probablemente mañana que tengo tiempo.

Comment: Pienso que una mejor solución a largo plazo es que implementes una clase con el patron singleton.

Comment: @eyllanesc pienso que es arriesgado pensar que un singleton va a solucionar nada sin conocer el código y proyecto en su conjunto.