# En C++, ¿es obligatorio incluir el return 0; dentro de la función main?

Tags: c++

Por [sugerencia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/139428/63114) del usuario PaperBirdMaster me he animado ha realizar la pregunta que se indica en el título de este post.

Básicamente, como le comenté a dicho usuario, he visto en diferentes respuestas de SO que en C++ no es necesario incluir la instrucción `return 0;` en la función `main` ya que el compilador es capaz de incluir dicha instrucción por su cuenta. ¿Cuánto de cierto hay en la afirmación anterior?

Personalmente, prefiero incluir el `return 0;` debido a que va en la línea de usar un `return` dentro de una función, pues por definición las funciones devuelven un valor. Sería distinto si el `main` lo declarase como `void main()`, lo cual no es estándar, pero al menos es válido en Visual Studio, por poner un ejemplo, y ahí si no vería la necesidad de incluir algún tipo de `return`.

Por otro lado, relacionado a todo lo anterior, ¿cuán válido es utilizar otro tipo de `return` como, por ejemplo, `return EXIT_SUCCESS;`, que se puede encontrar en uno de los libros sobre C++ de Luis Joyanes.

Gracias de antemano por sus respuestas y/o comentarios.

Comment: El return 0 se utiliza para ver que tu programa se ejecuto correctamente ya que si todo salio bien regresara un 0 y si hay algun error te regresara cualquier otra cosa menos 0, es por eso que se utiliza

Comment: si pero yo me pregunto mas específicamente ¿qué hace el sistema operativo con ese número?

Comment: Ese el *código de retorno* (return code) de la aplicación. Un cero generalmente indica que la app. fue exitosa. Cualquier otro valor implica un error o excepción que se debe estudiar caso a caso. El código está disponible para consulta por consola o dentro de un batch.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> ¿Cuánto de cierto hay en la afirmación anterior?

Atendiendo al [draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf) de C++14, en la sección 3.6.1 Encontramos lo siguiente:

> 5 A `return` statement in main has the effect of leaving the main function (destroying any objects with automatic
>   storage duration) and calling `std::exit` with the `return` value as the argument. If control reaches the end
>   of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing
>
> ```
> return 0;
> ```

Que viene a decir lo siguiente :

> La instrucción `return` provoca que la ejecución abandone la función *main* (los objetos que se salgan de ámbito serán eliminados). Además se llamará a `std::exit` con el valor usado en el `return` como argumento. Si la función *main* finaliza sin una instrucción `return` se ejecutará la instrucción:
>
> ```
> return 0;
> ```

Así que la respuesta es **NO**, no es obligatorio incluir la instrucción `return` en la función *main*.

Sí será obligatorio añadir esta instrucción cuando la aplicación necesite devolver diferentes valores en función del resultado de la ejecución (por ejemplo para indicar errores).

> Sería distinto si el main lo declarase como `void main()`, lo cual no es estándar, pero al menos es válido en Visual Studio, por poner un ejemplo, y ahí si no vería la necesidad de incluir algún tipo de `return`.

Si leemos el apartado 2 de la sección antes comentada (3.6.1):

> 2 An implementation shall not predefine the main function. This function shall not be overloaded. **It shall have a return type of type int**, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined. All implementations shall allow both.

Que básicamente viene a decir que la función *main* **debe devolver un tipo `int`**. Por supuesto que, por cuestiones de compatibilidad, hay compiladores que *tragan* con `void`... pero cuidado con esto porque nada te garantiza que la siguiente versión del compilador vaya a aceptar tanto esa como otras tantas licencias... puedes encontrarte con la situación de tener que editar decenas de líneas de código solo para que el programa vuelva a compilar.

> cuán válido es utilizar otro tipo de return como, por ejemplo, return EXIT_SUCCESS;, que se puede encontrar en uno de los libros sobre C++ de Luis Joyanes.

`EXIT_SUCCESS` no es un tipo sino que es una constante:

```
#define EXIT_SUCCESS 0
```

Y está disponible tanto para C como para C++ a través de las librerías `stdlib.h` o `cstdlib`.

Por tanto, `EXIT_SUCCESS` es, en tu caso, equivalente a poner `return 0;`.

Entonces, ¿Por qué usar `EXIT_SUCCESS` si se escribe más?

Bueno, piensa que tanto C como C++ no se han diseñado para una arquitectura en concreto... si te encuentras con un Sistema Operativo en el que una aplicación debe devolver un valor diferente de 0 cuando finaliza correctamente la macro se adaptará sin problemas mientras que el `0` te tocará modificarlo a mano.

Comment: He encontrado el siguiente enlace para [c++17](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function), ya que la web de ISO obliga a pagar para descargar el estándar. Dice que si no hay un return, se asume un `return 0;` al final del flujo

Comment: @PabloLozano es algo que no ha cambiado en el estándar

Comment: lo comentaba simplemente para completar tu respuesta, ya que explícitamente nombras c++14

Comment: @PabloLozano nombro c++14 porque es el mas reciente con permiso de c++17 (que aun le falta extenderse un poco). Podría haber cogido cualquier otro estándar y diría exactamente lo mismo... pero este es el más actual. No tiene demasiado sentido regirse por estándares antiguos salvo que no haya más remedio

Comment: @PabloLozano puedes encontrar el borrador más reciente (y gratuito) del estándar de C++ en [isocpp](https://isocpp.org/std).

Answer (score 15):

> He visto [...] que en C++ no es necesario incluir la instrucción `return 0;` en la función `main` ya que el compilador es capaz de incluir dicha instrucción por su cuenta. ¿Cuánto de cierto hay en la afirmación anterior?

Es cierto, con matices.

1. Es necesario retornar un valor en funciones que retornen valores o se incurrirá en [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido)... **excepto en el caso de `main`**, cuyo comportamiento está definido.
2. El compilador no incluirá ninguna instrucción `return` **excepto en el caso de `main`**, pero lo hace para seguir el estándar, no porque sea una decisión que el compilador tome a su libre albedrío.

En [el estándar de C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) el texto relevante sobre el primer punto es (traducción y resaltado mío):

> #### 9.6.3.2 La instrucción `return`.
>
> La *expresión-o-lista-entre-llaves* de una instrucción `return` recibe el nombre de operando. **Una instrucción `return` sin operando debe ser usada sólo en funciones cuyo tipo es `void` *constante o volátil***, un constructor o un destructor. **Una instrucción `return` con cualquier otro operando sebe ser usada sólo en una función cuyo tipo de retorno no sea `void` *constante o volátil***; [...] **llegar al final de un constructor, destructor, o función con tipo de retorno `void` *constante o volátil* es equivalente a una instrucción `return` sin operando. En cualquier otro caso, llegar al final de una función diferente a `main` resulta en comportamiento indefinido**.

El texto relevante sobre el segundo punto es (traducción y resaltado mío):

> #### 6.6.1.5
>
> Una instrucción `return` en `main` tiene como efecto abandonar la función `main` (destruyendo cualquier objeto con duración de almacenamiento automática) y llamar `std::exit` con el valor de la instrucción `return` como argumento. **Si el control abandona la declaración de `main`, el efecto es equivalente a llamar la instrucción `return` con operando `0`**.

---

#### Conclusión.

Si bien es cierto que un compilador de C++ que siga el estándar se comporta de manera definida en funciones `main` sin instrucción `return`, yo (personalmente) me opongo a ello por los siguientes motivos:

- **Denota intencionalidad**: Escribir explícitamente la instrucción de retorno, muestra la intencionalidad del programador; si se deja que lo haga de manera automática queda la duda de si es una omisión accidental o intencionada<sup>1</sup>.
- **Homogeniza el código**: es perturbador el seguir unas normas determinadas y estrictas para todas las funciones del código excepto para una. Si además la función `main` tuviese otros retornos explícitos, sería aún más perturbador confiar en un `return` implícito mientras los otros no lo han sido<sup>1</sup>.
- **Sigue el [principio de mínima sorpresa](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_la_M%C3%ADnima_Sorpresa)**: Si una función tiene un retorno, lo sorprendente sería que no retornase nada (al menos de manera visiblemente explícita).

---

1. Podría añadirse un comentario al final de `main` para mostrar esa intencionalidad:

   ```
   int main() {
       try {
           run();
       } catch (const std::exception &) {
           return 1;
       }
       /* devolvemos 0 de manera automatica segun se establece
          en el punto 6.6.1.5 del estandar del lenguaje. */
   }
   ```

   Pero ¡es mucho más sencillo simplemente escribir la instrucción `return` adecuada!.

Comment: Su respuesta y la del usuario eferion son muy buenas, pero al final me voy a decantar por la otra respuesta. De todos modos, gracias por animarme a realizar la pregunta y también por haberla respondido.

Comment: La respuesta de eferion es objetivamente más completa. Mi respuesta contiene lo mismo pero añade una valoración personal.

Answer (score 0):

Explicando este tema de la instrucción "**return 0;**"; esta lo que hace es finalizar una función y devolver el control a donde se llamó la función. Por ejemplo: En el caso de un simple programa de C++ que escribe "Hola Mundo"; lo que hace esta instrucción es finalizar "**main**" y devolverle el control al sistema operacional de nuestra máquina; el valor **0** le dice al sistema operacional que el programa ha finalizado correctamente. Segun la última versión de C++; este return 0 puede omitirse y el programa trabajará normalmente!.

Answer (score 0):

Comprendo los argumentos y las buenas prácticas de programación. Pero saliendo de convención podrías retornarle un 99 y tendría sentido sólo para tí, manipulando el main desde alguna consola y accediendo a ese valor de retorno.

Comment: Cualquier salida que no sea 0 solo va a tener sentido para aquel que conozca las posibles salidas del programa. El mecanismo por defecto tratará cualquier salida distinta de 0 como un error genérico