# Función "random" devuelve siempre 83

Tags: c++

En este script de c++ la función rando_btw debería devolver un número aleatorio entre min y max (en este caso entre 0 y 100) pero por algún motivo siempre devuelve 83 ¿Alguien sabría decirme por qué?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int rando_btw(int min, int max)
{
    return rand() % (max - min) + min;
}

int foo = rando_btw(0,100);

int main()
{
    srand(time (NULL));
    cout << time (NULL);
    cout << foo << endl; 
}
```

Comment: En relación a lo que la usuaria Paula_Plus_Plus menciona sobre el uso de `std::rand` puedes revisar el siguiente [video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es porque llamas a `rando_btw()` antes de entrar en `main()` y por tanto antes de inicializar la semilla. Cambia el lugar donde la llamas, así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int rando_btw(int min, int max)
{
    return rand() % (max - min) + min;
}

int foo;
int main()
{
    srand(time (NULL));
    foo = rando_btw(0,100);

    cout << time (NULL);
    cout << foo << endl; 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> En este script de c++

El lenguaje C++ es compilado, no interpretado. El código de C++ son programas, no scripts.

> Siempre devuelve 83 ¿Alguien sabría decirme por qué?

La [respuesta de abulafia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/144601/2742) ha señalado el problema, pero no ha mencionado otros problemas que presenta tu código que podría valer la pena tratar:

#### Ámbito de variables.

En C++ se aconseja que el ámbito de las variables sea lo más pequeño posible. En tu caso, has declarado el entero `foo` en el ámbito global pudiendo pertenecer al ámbito de la función `main`.

#### Función `main`.

Has olvidado añadir el retorno a la función `main`, yo aconsejo ponerlo siempre, consulta [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/139624/en-c-es-obligatorio-incluir-el-return-0-dentro-de-la-funci%C3%B3n-main) para más información al respecto.

#### Evita `std::endl`.

En la mayoría de casos no es necesario usar `std::endl`, consulta [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/47839/c-instrucci%C3%B3n-endl) para más detalles al respecto.

#### Cláusula `using`.

En general, se aconseja evitar el `using namespace std` o si se usa, limitarlo al ámbito más pequeño posible, consulta [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/460/por-qu%C3%A9-el-usar-using-namespace-std-se-considera-mala-pr%C3%A1ctica) para más información al respecto.

#### Se desaconsjea el uso de `std::rand`.

El algoritmo de `std::rand` no forma parte de la especificación de C++ y en consecuencia puede no ser portable con resultados y rendimiento cuestionables. Por ello [se está estudiando deprecarlo](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3924.pdf).

La librería estándar de C++ ofrece [utilidades estándar de generación de números pseudo-aleatorios](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) desde 2011.

#### Estás falseando la distribución.

La distribución numérica de `std::rand` es homogénea entre `0` y [`RAND_MAX`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/RAND_MAX), esto significa que cualquier número dentro de dicho rango tiene las mismas probabilidades de ser esogido (1 entre `RAND_MAX`).

Al hacer módulo (`%`) sobre el resultado de `std::rand` rompes la homogeneidad si el divisor no es múltiplo de `RAND_MAX`. Suponiendo un `RAND_MAX` de `32767` con un módulo sobre `100` obtenemos que los números del `0` al `67` tienen una probabilidad de aparición mayor que los números del `68` al `99`.

#### Propuesta.

Teniendo en cuenta todo lo anterior, tu código podría quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
// No se incluye ninguna cabecera de C

int rando_btw(int min, int max)
{
    // Tenemos control sobre el algoritmo y distribución a usar.
    static std::random_device device;
    static std::mt19937 generador(device());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distribucion(min, max);

    /* Generamos un número pseudo-aleatorio con el algoritmo
    mt19937 distribuido uniformemente entre min y max */
    return distribucion(generador);
}

int main()
{
    // La cláusula using sólo afecta a main
    using namespace std;
    // La variable foo sólo existe en main
    int foo = rando_btw(0,100);
    // No usamos endl.
    cout << foo << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```