# Error al hacer un directorio telefónico en c++

Tags: c++, dev-c++, números-enteros

Soy principiante en esto de la programación. Estoy tratando de hacer un programa tipo agenda telefónica que me guarde en un **.txt** la información.Este es el código que hice:

```
#include iostream   
#include fstream   
#include stdio.h   
using namespace std;   
string nombre;   
double telefono;   
int main(){   
    ofstream dato;   
    dato.open("directorio telefonico.txt");   
    printf("Creacion de datos\nNombre:");   
    getline(cin,nombre);   
    fflush(stdin);   
    printf("\nNumero de telefono:");   
    scanf("%i", &telefono);   
    fflush(stdin); 
}
```

Luego guardo la variable **teléfono** y **nombre** en el archivo `dato`.

Esto me crea un archivo **.txt** y el nombre se guarda bien, sin embargo, al momento de ingresar el número; ej: 221, me aparece un resultado distinto que es: 1.09189e-321.

¿Alguien sabe a que se debe este error?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double telefono; 
scanf("%i", &telefono);
```

Le dices que vas a leer un entero `int` y le pasas una variable `double`, así que puede pasar cualquier cosa.

Como un número de teléfono es un entero, `int` o `long` son tipos más adecuados. Así que simplemente reemplaza la primera línea por.

```
int telefono;
```

Nota: lo que realmente se usa habitualmente son strings, para permitir separadores, controlar mejor la longitud, etc.

Comment: Ya reemplace lo que me dijiste, y cuando hago la prueba con los primeros digitos de mi telefono (0426) se almacena otro dato en el archivo de texto (278). ¿Sabes a que se debe?

Comment: `0` al principio normalmente se interpreta como "este número es octal", 426 en octal es 278 en decimal. En general, los números no tienen (ni guardan) ceros a la izquierda; es otra ventaja de los strings.

Answer (score 2):

Lo raro es que siquiera te compile, para empezar tienes las inclusiones mal:

```
#include iostream   
#include fstream   
#include stdio.h
```

Debería ser:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
```

Pero es que además estás programando en C++, por lo que no deberías usar inclusiones de C, en lugar de `<stdio.h>` deberías usar `<cstdio>` lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/48305/2742) para saber por qué. Así que lo anterior debería ser:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>
```

Pero la cabecera `<cstdio>` se usa para interacción con el usuario, lo mismo que la cabecera `<iostream>`, lo que quiere decir que estás incluyendo dos utilidades para la misma cosa, elimina la cabecera de C y quedaría así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
```

Pero entonces no tienes acceso a `printf` ni `scanf`, pero no pasa nada porque tenemos las utilidades de interacción con el usuario de C++ `std::cin` y `std::cout`, por lo que tu código quedaría así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string> // Si usas string, añade su cabecera.

int main(){   
    using namespace std;

    string nombre;   
    double telefono;   
    ofstream dato("directorio telefonico.txt");

    cout << "Creacion de datos\nNombre:");
    getline(cin,nombre);   
    fflush(stdin);   
    cout << "\nNumero de telefono:";

    cin >> telefono;
    fflush(stdin);

    return 0;
}
```

Si te fijas he hecho algunos cambios adicionales:

- He quitado las variables globales `nombre` y `telefono` para moverlas al ámbito de `main`; en C++ se aconseja que las variables tengan el ámbito más pequeño posible.
- También he movido la cláusula `using namespace` al ámbito de `main` por el mismo motivo que el punto anterior.
- He añadido la cabecera `<string>` que estabas usando sin incluirla, ésta cabecera se incluye a través de otras cabeceras estándar pero no debes confiar en que eso se mantendrá así, por lo que es necesario incluirla si la usas.
- El `ofstream` se puede construir pasándole el nombre del archivo a tratar, no es necesario llamar a `open`.
- La función `main` [debe devolver un valor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/139624/2742).

Con todos estos cambios tu programa funcionaría, pero como ha mencionado [SJuan76](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/173642/2742), tiene más sentido que el número de teléfono sea un valor entero (`int`) antes que un número en coma flotante (`double`).