# Error- no matching function for call to 'getline(std::ifstream&, int&, std::string&)' (dev c++)

Tags: c++, dev-c++

estoy con la cuestión de hacer un directorio telefónico. Me salta el error que coloque en el título, en la línea "getline(dato,numero, nombre);"(por cierto, esta casi al final señalada con un comentario) y no se a que se debe.

```
/*programa para crear un archivo de texto, leer y agregar directorios telefonicos*/
  #include<stdio.h> //para el printf y el scanf
  #include<fstream> //para trabajar con los archivos
  #include<iostream>
  using namespace std;
  int opcion; //la variable para las opciones del switch
  string nombre; //la variable para guardar el nombre del contacto
  int numero; //la variable para guardar el numero de telefono

  int main(){ //funcion principal
  printf("Directorios telefonicos\n\n Opciones:\n 1-Crear archivo de 
  texto\n2-Agregar contactos\n3-Leer datos");
  //la linea anterior es como luciria el menu
  printf("\nIngresa una opcion:");
  cin>>opcion;
  system("cls");
  //limpiado luego de ingresar la opcion
  //empieza el switch
  switch(opcion){
    case 1:
        void crear();
        break;
    case 2:
        void agregar();
        break; 
    case 3:
        void leer();
        break;
    default:
        printf("Solo se admiten numeros del 1 al 3");   
               }//fin switch 
cin.get();
cin.get();
}
//fin funcion principal main


void crear(){ //funcion para crear el archivo de texto
    ofstream dato;
    string nombredArchivo;
    printf("Ingrese el nombre para el archivo:");
    getline(cin,nombredArchivo);
    dato.open(nombredArchivo.c_str(), ios::out);
    printf("El archivo se ha creado correctamente");
    dato.close();
              }

void agregar(){ //funcion para agregar contactos en el mismo documento
    string nombredArchivo;
    ofstream dato(nombredArchivo.c_str(), ios::app);
    printf("Agregar datos\nNombre:");
    getline(cin,nombre);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nNumero de telefono local:");
    scanf("%i", &numero);
    fflush(stdin);
    dato<<"\n"<<nombre;
    dato<<"\n"<<numero;
    dato.close();
}

void leer(){ //funcion para leer el documento
    string nombredArchivo;
    ifstream dato;
    dato.open(nombredArchivo.c_str(),ios::in);
    if(dato.fail()){
        printf("No se pudo abrir el archivo");
        exit(1);        
    }
    while(!dato.eof()){
        getline(dato,numero, nombre);//aca da el error
        cout<<nombre<<numero<<endl;
    }
    dato.close();
}
```

Comment: A que funcion tratas de llamar? no existe una funcion asi...

Answer (score 2):

> Me salta el error `no matching function for call to 'getline(std::ifstream&, int&, std::string&)'` y no se a que se debe.

Se debe principalmente a que no has leído el manual o no has echado un vistazo a la ayuda en pantalla que te ofrece DevC++.

---

La función [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) dispone de cuatro sobrecargas y ninguna de ellas recibe como parámetros un `std::ifstream` junto a un `int` y un `std::string`. La función `std::getline`, como su nombre indica sirve para obtener una línea de texto de un flujo (*stream*) de datos; parece que tú la estás usando para obtener dos datos separados.

Por lo que puedo entender en tu función `agregar`, cada entrada en tu directorio telefónico está compuesta de pares líneas, siendo la primera el nombre del contacto y la segunda el teléfono del mismo, así pues deberías obtener los datos así:

```
void leer() {
    string nombredArchivo;
    ifstream dato;
    dato.open(nombredArchivo.c_str(),ios::in);
    if(dato.fail()){
        printf("No se pudo abrir el archivo");
        exit(1);        
    }
    while(!dato.eof()){
        dato >> nombre;
        dato >> numero;
        cout<<nombre<<numero<<endl;
    }
    dato.close();
}
```

Tan sencillo como eso.

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

Te aconsejo echar un vistazo a [tu anterior pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/173741/2742) en que he señalado varias cosas que deberías mejorar de tu código:

- No uses variables globales; en C++ se aconseja que las variables tengan el ámbito más pequeño posible.
- No uses la cláusula `using namespace` en ámbito global.
- Usas la cabecera `<string>` sin incluirla, ésta cabecera se incluye a través de otras cabeceras estándar pero no debes confiar en que eso se mantendrá así, por lo que es necesario incluirla si la usas.
- El `ofstream` se puede construir pasándole el nombre del archivo a tratar, no es necesario llamar a `open`.
- La función `main` [debe devolver un valor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/139624/2742).
- No uses `<stdio.h>`, y si tienes que usarlo (que no deberías en este código) usa su versión C++: `<cstdio>` (lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/48305/2742) para saber por qué).