# La linea de codigo de la impresion no imprime bien

Tags: c++, array, bucles

Hice este código al momento de pedir los datos me sale bien pero después cuando quiero mostrar los datos que pedi la impresion sale mal, me podrian decir  por favor que tengo que hacer para que salga bien la impresion por favor.Dejo una imagen para que vean la impresion final, solo el nombre del ultimo libro nada mas me muestra .Por favor necesito de su ayuda para resolver esto y de antemano gracias[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

void main(){
    int lib;
    char libro[50];
    cout<<"Cantidad de libros: ";
    cin>>lib;
    for(int i=0;i<lib;i++){
        cout<<"Nombre del libro "<<i+1<<" :";
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(libro);
        cout<<endl;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<lib;i++){
        cout<<"Nombre del libro "<<i+1<<" : "<<libro<<endl;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` es una [comportamiendo indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido). Creo que debes usar `while(getchar() != '\n')` o algo.

Comment: Para mi lo mejor sería crear un estructura de nombre libros con las propiedade de nombres, luego ya definido tu estructura creas un array de estructuras.

Answer (score 3):

Tal y como ha dicho [iBug](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/193484/2742) quieres guardar dos libros, pero sólo tienes espacio para uno.

---

Si quieres más libros, necesitarás más espacio para libros, la solución propuesta por iBug es correcta y funcional (limitada  un máximo de 10 libros), pero yo te aconsejo una solución más acorde con el lenguaje, en primer lugar señalaré tus fallos más evidentes:

- Las cabeceras `<stdlib.h>` y `<stdio.h>` son de C, no de C++, si realmente necesitas usarlas (que no las necesitas) debes usar los equivalentes de C++: `<cstdlib>` y  `<cstdio>`. Consulta [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/48268/2742) para saber por qué.
- La manera de trabajar con cadenas de caracteres en C++ es usando objetos de tipo [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) (accesibles tras incluir la cabecera `<string>`) no con formaciones<sup>1</sup> de caracteres.
- La manera de trabajar con colecciones de tamaño arbitrario en C++ es usando contenedores de objetos, por ejemplo [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) (accesibles tras incluir la cabecera `<list>`) no con formaciones<sup>1</sup>.
- No se aconseja el uso de `using namespace std;` en el ámbito global, si fuese necesario usarlo (no suele serlo) debe usarse en el ámbito más pequeño posible. Consulta [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/460/2742) para saber por qué.
- No suele ser necesario usar `std::endl`, es más eficiente usar un salto de línea explícito `\n`, consulta [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/47839/2742) para saber por qué.
- La función `main`, **debe** devolver un valor. Consulta [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/139624/2742) para saber por qué.
- [Favorece el pre-incremento frente al post-incremento](https://vitaminacpp.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/leyenda-pre-y-post-incremento/).

Teniendo en cuenta todas estas correcciones tu código podría quedar así:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    using lista_libros = std::list<std::string>;

    lista_libros libros;
    int lib;

    std::cout << "Cantidad de libros: ";
    std::cin >> lib;

    for (int i = 0; i < lib; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Nombre del libro " << i + 1 << " :";
        std::string libro;

        std::cin >> libro;
        libros.push_back(libro);
    }

    lib = 0;

    for (const auto &libro : libros) {
        std::cout << "Nombre del libro " << ++lib << " : " << libro << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

1. También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*.

Answer (score 2):

Eres escribiendo `libro` en el bucle primero de `for` por cada vez. Creo que debes usar un array de arrays:

```
char libro[10][50];
//        ^^^^
cout<<"Cantidad de libros: ";
cin>>lib;
for(int i=0;i<lib;i++){
    cout<<"Nombre del libro "<<i+1<<" :";
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(libro[i]);
    cout<<endl;
}
for(int i=0;i<lib;i++){
    cout<<"Nombre del libro "<<i+1<<" : "<<libro[i]<<endl;
}
```