# Error con arreglos

Tags: c++, c++98

Hola a todos miren es que trato de resolver un problema con arreglos de menor y mayor y sacar su diferencia pero... el programa define bien el elemento mayor pero no el menor asi es el arreglo

**2 5 3 7 12 9 8 5 4 10**

**Define bien el mayor que en este caso es el 12**

**El menor lo define mal que imprime 10 y se supone que  debe ser 2**

Es el siguiente codigo

```
 #include<iostream>
 #define MAX 10002
 using namespace std;

int arr[MAX];
int mayor=arr[0], menor=arr[0];
int diferencia=0;

int main()
{
    for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)
    {
        cin>>arr[i];

        if(arr[i]>mayor)
        {
            mayor=arr[i];
        }

        if(arr[i]<menor);
        {
            menor=arr[i];
        }
    }
    cout<<menor<<" "<<mayor;
}
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería mucho

Comment: Te lo he editado un poco, para usar cabeceras estándar por si alguien quiere probarlo. Espero que no te moleste :-)

Answer (score 3):

Vayamos por partes:

```
int arr[MAX];
int mayor=arr[0], menor=arr[0];
```

En este momento, el contenido de `arr[0]` es desconocido. Puede ser cualquier cosa, porque no has inicializado el array.

Como no sabemos ese valor, igual resulta que `mayor` ya es mayor que cualquiera de los elementos que pongas(y no cambiaría en las iteraciones). O `menor` es menor que cualquiera de tus elementos (y no cambiaría en las iteraciones).

Por ejemplo, si `menor` empieza siendo 0, ninguno de los elementos de tu ejemplo lo reemplazaría. `menor` tiene que ser tan alto que estés seguro de que vas a encontrar un valor menor, `mayor` tan bajo que estés seguro de que vas a encontrar un valor mayor.

```
int diferencia=0;
int main() {
  for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)
  {
    cin>>arr[i];
```

Si no necesitas guardar los datos, realmente no necesitas un array. Si haces `int numero; cin >> numero;` funciona exactamente igual.

Naturalmente, en las líneas siguientes tendrías que cambiar `arr[i]` por `numero`.

```
    if(arr[i]>mayor) {
        mayor=arr[i];
    }
    if(arr[i]<menor);
```

Tienes un `;`, así que el `if` termina en la línea de arriba y el bloque de abajo se ejecuta siempre.

```
    {
        menor=arr[i];
    }
}
cout<<menor<<" "<<mayor;
```

La impresión es liosa porque se confunde con los datos de la última línea. Creo que eso es parte del problema; es mucho mejor: `cout << endl << "Menor :" << menor << endl << "Mayor: " << mayor << endl;`

```
}
```

Comment: No termino de compartir eso de usar `endl` de forma indiscriminada... además la respuesta, tal y como está descrita, se me antoja un poco complicada de seguir

Comment: Además, los arrays estáticos **sí** se inicializan. En el código que nos ocupa, tanto `mayor` como `menor` valen 0.

Answer (score 3):

Cuando empiezas a programar es muy normal que se escapen algunos detallitos pero ya una vez que llevas tiempo te percatas de ciertos detalles, tu error esta en que pusiste un `;` donde no debería ir uno.

```
  #include<iostream>
  #define MAX 10002
  using namespace std;

  int arr[MAX];
  int mayor=arr[0], menor=arr[0];
  int diferencia=0;

int main()
{
    for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)
    {
        cin>>arr[i];

        if(arr[i]>mayor)
        {
            mayor=arr[i];
        }

        if(arr[i]<menor); <---- precisamente aquí
        {
           menor=arr[i];
        }
    }
    cout<<menor<<" "<<mayor;
}
```

Comment: Te has olvidado añadir un [retorno a la función `main`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/139624/2742)

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente el programa tiene dos errores. Uno ya te lo han indicado y es que se te ha colado un `;` después de un `if`:

```
if(arr[i]<menor);
//              ^
```

Ese punto y coma hace que el `if` no haga absolutamente nada... detalles tontos del lenguaje. Para verlo más claramente podríamos sustituir ese punto y coma por dos llaves:

```
if(arr[i]<menor){ }
{
  menor = arr[i];
}
```

Ahora se ve mejor que ese punto y coma anula el condicional.

Por otro lado la inialización de `menor` no es correcta.

Los arrays globales se inicializan automáticamente, no así aquellos que pertenecen a una función. Es decir:

```
int arr[MAX]; // Todos sus elementos valen 0
              // Pero únicamente porque es variable global!!!

int main()
{
  int arr2[MAX]; // Array no inicializado!!!
}
```

Pues bien, lo siguiente que haces después de declarar el arreglo es declarar e inicializar `mayor` y `menor`:

```
int mayor=arr[0], menor=arr[0];
```

Y aquí empiezan los problemas... esta inicialización hace que `mayor=menor=0`. Si posteriormente le damos valores a `arr[0]`, el valor de `mayor` y `menor` **no va a cambiar** automáticamente. Su valor de partida va a ser **siempre** 0.

Esta inicialización nos plantea un problema y es que para que `menor` encuentre el número más pequeño, el mismo deberá ser igual o menor que 0. De no ser así el programa no va a funcionar.

Para evitar este jaleo de mínimos y máximos yo utilizaría punteros:

```
int* mayor = arr;
int* menor = arr;

for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++)
{
    cin>>arr[i];

    if(arr[i] > *mayor)
    {
        mayor = &arr[i];
    }

    if(arr[i] < *menor)
    {
       menor = &arr[i];
    }
}

cout << *menor << ' ' << *mayor;
```

Esta solución usa punteros en vez de variables. Así, `menor` no almacena un valor propio, sino que apuntará al elemento más pequeño (lo mismo para `mayor`).

Si usar punteros no es una posibilidad, entonces hay que prestar especial atención a la inicialización de `menor` y `mayor`. Tirando del estándar lo mejor es usar `std::numeric_limits`:

```
int menor = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
int mayor = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
```

Lo que hacemos aquí es inicializar `menor` con el número más grande que puede almacenarse en un `int`, de esta forma cualquier número que introduzca el usuario será igual o más pequeño y, en consecuencia, el algoritmo será capaz de detectarlo como más pequeño. En `mayor`, en cambio, almacenamos el número más pequeño posible, de tal forma que cualquier número que introduzca el usuario sea igual o más grande.