# Comparar Strings en C++

Tags: c++

tengo que hacer un programa en el cual he alojado 10 grupos de Heavy Metal, y despues pedir al usuario que introduzca 10 grupos, y en funcion de los aciertos que tenga el programa sacara una cosa u otra, no consigo dar con el problema, a ver si me pueden echar una mano, saludos!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void main() {

    string gruposPredeterminados[10] = { "Slayer", "Slipknot", "Iron Maiden", "Metallica", "Judas Priest", "AC/DC", "Black Sabbath", "Kiss", "Megadeth", "Pantera" };
    string gruposUsuario[10];
    int aciertos = 0;

    cout << "Ingresa 10 grupos de Heavy Metal: \n";

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        getline(cin, gruposUsuario[i]);

        if (gruposUsuario[i] == gruposPredeterminados[i])
        {
            aciertos++;
        }
    }


    switch (aciertos)
    {
    case 10: cout << "Amo del metal!";
        break;
    case 9: cout << "True metal";
        break;
    case 8: cout << "True metal";
        break;
    case 7: cout << "True metal";
        break;
    case 6: cout << "Metalero";
        break;
    case 5: cout << "Metalero";
        break;
    case 4: cout << "Metalero noob";
        break;
    case 3: cout << "Metalero noob";
        break;
    case 2: cout << "Meta que?";
        break;
    case 1: cout << "Meta que?";
    default: cout << "Tu ets mes de Pacha, oi?";
        break;
    }

    system("pause");

}
```

Comment: ¿ Podrías explicar/detallar el problema exacto ? ¿ De compilación, de funcionamiento ? Esperar que alguien, para poder ayudarte, tenga que compilar y ejecutar tu programa ... ¡ Ayudanos a ayudarte !

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos! En mi cabeza sabia que estaba mal el tema de comparar el valor X[i] con Y[i], ya que como bien habeis dicho solo estaria bien si el usuario lo escribe en el mismo orden, de todas formas, he visto que habeis utilizado dos formas, con compare y utilizando dos for, cual seria la mas eficaz?

Comment: @DanCezanneGalavan La que usa el `compare` no soluciona tu problema, a no ser que uses el `compare` Y dos `for`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estás sumando aciertos sólo si el valor de la posición `i` de `gruposUsuario` coincide el valor en la misma posición en `gruposPredeterminados`. Esto significa que aunque el usuario acierte todos los grupos, no se le dará por bueno a no ser que los acierte en el mismo orden.

Tienes que comprobar si un valor está en cualquiera de las posiciones, no en una sola:

```
for (int entrada = 0; entrada < 10; ++entrada)
{
    getline(cin, gruposUsuario[i]);

    for (int verificacion = 0; verificacion < 10; ++verificacion)
    {
        if (gruposUsuario[entrada] == gruposPredeterminados[verificacion])
        {
            ++aciertos;
        }
    }
}
```

Pero este código es horrible, además exige que el usuario acierte incluso las mayúsculas/minúsculas (No sería lo mismo "*AC/DC*" que "*Ac/Dc*").

#### Propuesta.

Separa la obtención de datos...

```
cout << "Ingresa 10 grupos de Heavy Metal: \n";

for (auto &grupo : gruposUsuario)
{
    getline(cin, grupo);
}
```

...  de la verificación:

```
for (const auto &grupo : gruposUsuario)
{
    aciertos += count(begin(gruposPredeterminados), end(gruposPredeterminados), grupo) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

También puedes simplificar tu `switch`:

```
switch (aciertos)
{
case 10:
    cout << "Amo del metal!";
    break;
case 9:
case 8:
case 7:
    cout << "True metal";
    break;
case 6:
case 5:
    cout << "Metalero";
    break;
case 4:
case 3:
    cout << "Metalero noob";
    break;
case 2:
    cout << "Meta que?";
    break;
case 1:
    cout << "Meta que?";
default:
    cout << "Tu ets mes de Pacha, oi?";
    break;
}
```

Puedes ver mi propuesta funcionando en [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/W7WuEgNFf5hroHLe). He hecho cambios adicionales a tu código:

- Uso el `for` de rango por claridad.
- Uso la función [`std::count`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) para ver si el elemento existe<sup>1</sup> en la formación<sup>2</sup> de destino.
- Las funciones libres de obtención de rango [`std::begin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) y [`std::end`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end).

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

- Este es StackOverflow en Español, debiste poner algún grupo que cante en nuestro idioma ò_ó.
- El algoritmo, tal y como está, contará como 10 aciertos si pones 10 veces un valor que existe en la formación de referencia (pero puedes solucionando dando la vuelta a la comprobación: busca en la entrada de usuario los valores predeterminados).
- No es necesaria la cláusula `using namespace std;` pues tan sólo es una ayuda a la escritura; no pasa nada por usarla pero si la usas procura que sea en el ámbito más pequeño posible; lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/460/2742) para saber más del tema.
- Procura favorecer el pre-decremento (o incremento) frente al post-decremento (o incremento), lee [este artículo](https://vitaminacpp.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/leyenda-pre-y-post-incremento/) para saber más del tema.
- La función `main` **debe devolver `int`** (no `void`), lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/139624/2742) para saber por qué.

---

1. Es un poco más sencillo que usar [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), pero menos eficiente.
2. También conocidas como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.

Comment: Gracias compi! La mayoria de ajustes que dices son malas practicas de clase...hemos empezado hace nada y desde el primer dia nos han dado estas pautas, y si te buscas la vida e intentas usar codigo que no este en el temario tristemente te lo echan hacia atras...de todas formas no dudes en que vaya a echarle un ojo a lo que me has dicho, muchas gracias!

Comment: @DanCezanneGalavan eso que me explicas me entristece, me dan ganas de charlar con quien os da esas pautas para despotricar un rato.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas usar la función **compare** para comparar las strings de lo contrario puede darte problemas en muchos casos.

He modificado también los case del switch para evitar la repetición de código.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string gruposPredeterminados[10] = { "Slayer", "Slipknot", "Iron Maiden", "Metallica", "Judas Priest", "AC/DC", "Black Sabbath", "Kiss", "Megadeth", "Pantera" };
    string gruposUsuario[10];
    int aciertos = 0;

    cout << "Ingresa 10 grupos de Heavy Metal: \n";

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        getline(cin, gruposUsuario[i]);

        if (gruposUsuario[i].compare(gruposPredeterminados[i]) == 0)
        {
            aciertos++;
        }
    }


    switch (aciertos)
    {
    case 10: cout << "Amo del metal!";
        break;
    case 9:
    case 8:
    case 7:
        cout << "True metal";
        break;
    case 6:
    case 5:
        cout << "Metalero";
        break;
    case 4: 
    case 3: 
        cout << "Metalero noob";
        break;
    case 2: cout << "Meta que?";
        break;
    case 1: cout << "Meta que?";
    default: cout << "Tu ets mes de Pacha, oi?";
        break;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿ Que tiene de malo usar `==` para comparar `std::string( )` ? ¿ Seguro que el problema del usuario es ese ?

Comment: No es ese el error pero creo que es una practica mucho mejor ya que ofrece muchas más posibilidades tanto para comprar strings cual es mayor y poder realizar posteriores ordenaciones. Igual que el caso de modificación de los case entendí por la vaga explicación que ofreció que necesitaba una optimización de código. @Trauma

Comment: @solamente está bien que menciones (aquello que crees que son) buenas prácticas, pero no respondes la pregunta.