# numero de elementos en vector

Tags: c++, array, archivo, consola, c++11

Tengo el siguiente código que crea un vector(a partir de un fichero de texto) con los elementos que cumplen el requerimiento

```
bool IsValid(vector<int> digits) //el primer dígito es menor que la suma de los dos últimos
{
    if(digits[0] < (digits[1] + digits[2] ))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

así es como lo aplico para crear el nuevo vector y el fichero de texto saliente en el que quiero escribir los elementos de este nuevo vector

```
int main()
{
    ofstream outfile ("test.txt");
    outfile << "512 456 789 123 123 432 \n 123 243 \n \n 412\n  " << endl;
    ifstream in("test.txt");
    ofstream out("output.txt");
    char tmp;
    vector<int> digits;
    try
    {
    while(in.get(tmp))
    {
        if(tmp!=' ' and tmp!='\n')
        {
            digits.push_back(tmp-'0');

            if(digits.size()==3)
            {
                if(IsValid(digits)){
                    cout<<"number of elements="<<digits.size()<<endl;
                    out<<digits[0]<<digits[1]<<digits[2]<<endl;
                    for(int i=0; i<digits.size();i++){
                    cout<<digits[i]<<endl;}
                }
                 digits.clear();

            }
        }

    }

    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {

    }
    out.close();
    in.close();

}
```

Mi duda es que cuando escribo `cout<<"number of elements="<<digits.size()<<endl;` no recibo en consola el numero de elementos total sino me dice que hay 3 elementos cuando lo que yo quiero que me diga cuántos elementos hay en total
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

> Mi duda es que cuando escribo `cout<<"number of elements="<<digits.size()<<endl;` no recibo en consola el numero de elementos total.

Te equivocas, sí que recibes el número de elementos total, son exactamente tres elementos porque sólo tienes posibilidad de consultar `digits.size()` cuando dicho valor es exactamente tres:

```
if(digits.size()==3) // <--- El tamaño es exactamente tres?
{
    if(IsValid(digits)){
        cout<<"number of elements="<<digits.size()<<endl; // <--- Imprime el tamaño
        // … 
    }
    // …
}
```

Por otro lado, nunca tendrás más de tres elementos, ya que en el momento en que obtienes tres elementos borras el contenido y vuelves a empezar de cero:

```
if(digits.size()==3) // <--- El tamaño es exactamente tres?
{
    // … 
    digits.clear(); // <--- Vacía el contenedor.
}
```

---

Supongo que lo que en realidad quieres es que los números sean de exactamente tres cifras y después filtrarlos por el criterio que detallas, lo más cercano a ese objetivo conservando la mayor parte de tu código [sería](https://tio.run/##fVRdcpswEH7nFFs6E8N44tjY6Y/Bfu8F@pJ4OrJYbE1BokikaTM@Ui/Q1xzMWUAYMDPRGKz90X77aXfheX574Px8/igkT8sYIRJKmwJZtnU63RNyo4q@JmmdnFILeQDJMtQ54wjaxKHj7JVK4Zv@zlIRe83xSEizhVgchNE@3N1hCnkhMiwgfv1HSgWoIUOpCvhVIqQMdJkxILRUaYjpef2fGpEp7bw4QEskXhPtYb6DCFphsYOphXkIduD7tXO1CjRlIcEUJYa1ElON19aEkTJ0To5D@ULGhPR8C6gsa1ClSUSK4LkGtZmZZ@P6TcTWEkXg3i8CWN1/gs9fvsIiWNbPahnAo6y3wWpZbem3WgT0Brc6hTJOQ0vPolEGY5xeKp5Lr7wc2PmRFWCyvJHGBRjoe@YtPLG0RGs3xZ/6v6H/@0jMPCFnBzQexbY3@3K5QSoIqT9sJjABJmNohEc56UrQOVeryWWWl/r4Y8/4z@r47WQ@IRIDv0ulZ1r8Rc/fbJb@wGEYtqZW0@iFto0XjjxtZJ4iK7wr@8kZ7k5NXgn1qMdKatkbTkRFzAzC2mL6IwRKvx2Fi7vvj3OuC0e1jCJXltmeJkMl1KNIQ2H0xo0iS6q5hCjqeuV61UEuWDQffWkxkILde4GIqVfNgdjMQxDdMZtDKKbTd4l0OKLFOY3c7a02Bs4MP3pcSW2qb8l6jc8ccyOUvAFsO67nTzBUO6WxrR016EC2cz2nmT6f3wA):

```
vector<int> digits;
vector<vector<int>> values;

while(in.get(tmp))
{
    if(tmp!=' ' and tmp!='\n')
    {
        digits.push_back(tmp-'0');

        if(digits.size()==3)
        {
            values.push_back(digits); // Guardar el número candidato
            digits.clear(); // Dejar el contenedor listo para el siguiente candidato
        }
    }
}

for (auto &candidate : values)
    if(IsValid(candidate)){ // Validar candidatos.
        cout<<"number of elements="<<values.size()<<endl;
        out<<candidate[0]<<candidate[1]<<candidate[2]<<endl;
        for(int i=0; i<candidate.size();i++){
            cout<<candidate[i]<<endl;}
        }
    }
```

Pero tu código puede ser mejorado en muchos puntos:

1. No necesitas un condicional para devolver verdadero o falso, la propia expresión ya es verdadera o falsa:

   ```
   bool IsValid(vector<int> digits)
   {
       return digits[0] < (digits[1] + digits[2]);
   }
   ```
2. No utilices vectores de dígitos para almacenar números, almacena números:

   ```
   bool IsValid(int value)
   {
       return (value / 100) < (((value / 10) % 10) + (value % 10));
   }
   ```
3. No leas la información carácter a carácter, lee dato a dato:

   ```
   vector<int> values;

   if (ifstream in{"test.txt"}) {
       int value;
       while ((in >> value) && value < 1000) // Lee números de tres dígitos
           values.push_back(value);
   }
   ```
4. Hace 30 años las pantallas eran de 80 caracteres de ancho y 20 líneas de alto, por lo tanto tenía sentido apretujar el código para mostrar en pantalla la mayor cantidad de información posible… hoy es día es completamente innecesario y absolutamente contraproducente: deja respirar a tu código, el código apretujado no mola más.
5. [`main` debería devolver un valor al acabar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/139624/2742).

#### [Propuesta](https://tio.run/##bVJbbtswEPwWT7FQUYdE0diWnb6s@r8X6FeAgqZWDhGKVEUyLWr4SL1Af3Mwd0XRebQRRGK5O5odzkr1/du9UqfTK22ViQ1CrZ0PA8puyx5zd6iCG55m2jOIRa/tHqzs0PdSIfjQbBjbOWfgi/8qjW64tgHupHGDgPkcDfSD7nCA5v73XgcH6KFD6wb4HhGMBB87CdTEOA8Nrfs/JujOeXZgQM@AIQ4WeGKEOSwXCwE1cP4kI@B12t@cYekoNuzI2Kimk9pyQYSFboG7fBtwMbTa4KEM6MNl@BnKowACFbkAdQ3l1bKC9dU7eP/hIyyrVVrrVQXXNoXVejWG9K6XFe0UlRtWUONisrEmAdvRj4ienEoK9FmBtv83z/ZFJJrix82og5OnsM0sAmazKSIbyI2FIFwxNbjso7/5tpPqlk/YLOXfax9K2vr4rG9LvnHlrA8gI81ppqRtdCMDwqesfwImtvOwH0AiFwtF1Mk5G7sdzd21gAZp5MF/LsdClur1L@RiTFxc24v0aUGHx665skmlTPpy9cjSGm@af5cFzf50@gs).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

bool IsValid(int valor) //el primer dígito es menor que la suma de los dos últimos
{
    return (valor / 100) < (((valor / 10) % 10) + (valor % 10));
}

int main()
{
    if (ofstream outfile{"test.txt"}) {
        outfile << "512 456 789 123 123 432 \n 123 243 \n \n 412\n  \n";
    }

    vector<int> values;

    if (ifstream in{"test.txt"}) {
        int value;
        while ((in >> value) && value < 1000)
            values.push_back(value);
    }

    if (ofstream out{"output.txt"}) {
        for (const auto &candidate : values) {
            if (IsValid(candidate)) {
                cout << "number of elements=" << values.size() << '\n'
                    << candidate << '\n';
                out << candidate << '\n';
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: cuando ejecuto tu propuesta recibo los siguientes errores: (He cambiado los nombres de fichero de entrada y salida para no perder mi código)stack3.c++:18:18: error: variable declaration in condition must have an initializer
    if (ofstream outfile{"test21.txt"}) {
                 ^
stack3.c++:18:25: error: expected ')'
    if (ofstream outfile{"test21.txt"}) {
                        ^
stack3.c++:18:8: note: to match this '('
    if (ofstream outfile{"test21.txt"}) {   Alguna propuesta?

Comment: Compila con C++11 o superior.

Comment: Creo que compilo con c++11(uso Visual Studio con la extensión de C++Intelligense y Code Runner)

Comment: Entonces o está equivocado el compilador o lo estás tu. Creo que puede ser lo segundo, ya que ese código está funcionando en el compilador de TIO, tal y como puede verse en el enlace de la respuesta.