# No me funciona la Sobrecarga en C++

Tags: c++, sobrecarga

queria ver si me podian ayudar ya que me sale este mensaje de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me he estado guiando por un libro de C++ y la verdad tengo el mismo código que sale ahí, pero me salta ese error, el programa lo que hace es realizar sumas utilizando la sobrecarga de constructores.

Adjunto mi codigo:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class sumar{
  public:
    int suma(int a, int b);
    int suma(int a, int b, int c);
    float suma(float a, float b);
    float suma(float a, float b, float c);
  };

  /* Metodos */

  int sumar::suma(int a, int b){
    return (a+b);
  }
  int sumar::suma(int a, int b, int c){
    return (a+b+c);
  }
  float sumar::suma(float a, float b){
    return (float)(a+b);
  }
  float sumar::suma(float a, float b, float c){
    return (float) (a+b+c);
  }

  int main(void){
    sumar mi_suma;
    /* Primer meotodo */
    cout << "\n\nSuma 1: " << mi_suma(1,2);
    /* Segundo metodo */
    cout << "\nSuma 2: " << mi_suma(1,2,3);
    /* Tercer metodo */
    cout << "\nSuma 3: " << mi_suma(3.1,2.7);
    /* Cuarto metodo */
    cout << "\nSuma 4: " << mi_suma(3.1,2.7,10.2) << "\n\n";
  }
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Necesitas llamar el método desde tu objeto, de la forma:

```
objeto.método()
```

En tu caso el compilador cree que tiene que buscar una función llamada `mi_suma`, en vez de un método del objeto.

Para tu caso:

```
int main(void){
    sumar mi_suma;
    /* Primer meotodo */
    cout << "\n\nSuma 1: " << mi_suma.suma(1,2);
    /* Segundo metodo */
    cout << "\nSuma 2: " << mi_suma.suma(1,2,3);
    /* Tercer metodo */
    cout << "\nSuma 3: " << mi_suma.suma(3.1,2.7);
    /* Cuarto metodo */
    cout << "\nSuma 4: " << mi_suma.suma(3.1,2.7,10.2) << "\n\n";
  }
```

También te recomiendo usar la constante flotante con `f` al final para que el compilador lo interprete como un `float` y no como un `double`, así no tienes que hacer la sobrecarga para `double`, así:

```
int main(void){
    sumar mi_suma;
    /* Primer meotodo */
    cout << "\n\nSuma 1: " << mi_suma.suma(1,2);
    /* Segundo metodo */
    cout << "\nSuma 2: " << mi_suma.suma(1,2,3);
    /* Tercer metodo */
    cout << "\nSuma 3: " << mi_suma.suma(3.1f,2.7f);
    /* Cuarto metodo */
    cout << "\nSuma 4: " << mi_suma.suma(3.1f,2.7f,10.2f) << "\n\n";
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

El error es claro y conciso, tal vez no lo entiendes por estar en inglés. Te lo traduzco:

> ```
> type 'sumar' does not provide a call operator.
> ```

> ```
> el tipo 'sumar' no proporciona un operador de llamada.
> ```

Un operador de llamada es el operador paréntesis (`()`), puedes establecer parámetros arbitrarios a dicho operador igual que si fuese una función, los cambios que debes hacer a tu código para usar el operador de llamada son los siguientes:

```
class sumar{
public:
    int operator()(int a, int b);                // Operador de llamada (int, int)
    int operator()(int a, int b, int c);         // Operador de llamada (int, int, int)
    float operator()(float a, float b);          // Operador de llamada (float, float)
    float operator()(float a, float b, float c); // Operador de llamada (float, float, float)
};

int sumar::operator()(int a, int b){
    return (a+b);
}

int sumar::operator()(int a, int b, int c){
    return (a+b+c);
}

float sumar::operator()(float a, float b){
    return (float)(a+b);
}

float sumar::operator()(float a, float b, float c){
    return (float) (a+b+c);
}
```

Si en realidad querías llamar a la función miembro `sumar::suma`, las llamadas en `main` deberían ser así:

```
int main() {
    sumar mi_suma;
    /* Primer meotodo */
    cout << "\n\nSuma 1: " << mi_suma.suma(1,2);
    //                                ~~~~ <--- Llama a sumar::suma(int, int)
    /* Segundo metodo */
    cout << "\nSuma 2: " << mi_suma.suma(1,2,3);
    //                              ~~~~ <--- Llama a sumar::suma(int, int, int)
    /* Tercer metodo */
    cout << "\nSuma 3: " << mi_suma.suma(3.1,2.7);
    //                              ~~~~ <--- Debería llamar a sumar::suma(double, double)
    /* Cuarto metodo */
    cout << "\nSuma 4: " << mi_suma.suma(3.1,2.7,10.2) << "\n\n";
    //                              ~~~~ <--- Debería llamar a sumar::suma(double, double, double)
}
```

### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

1. No conviertas a `float` datos que ya son `float`, es bastante confuso:

   ```
   float sumar::suma(float a, float b){
       return (a+b); // 'a' y 'b' ya son float, la conversión es innecesaria
   }
   float sumar::suma(float a, float b, float c){
       return (a+b+c);  // 'a', 'b' y 'c' ya son float, la conversión es innecesaria
   }
   ```
2. El literal de `float` incluye el sufijo `f`, si no pones dicho sufijo cualquier número con coma flotante será `double`:

   ```
   cout << "\nSuma 3: " << mi_suma(3.1f, 2.7f);
   // Literales 'float' ------------> ^     ^
   cout << "\nSuma 4: " << mi_suma(3.1f, 2.7f, 10.2f) << "\n\n";
   // Literales 'float' ------------> ^     ^      ^
   ```
3. En [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), cuando un método no recibe parámetros, se deja su lista de parámetros vacía en lugar de poner `void`:

   ```
   int main() // Correcto.

   int main(void) // Incorrecto.
   ```
4. La función `main` *debe* devolver un valor. Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/139624/en-c-es-obligatorio-incluir-el-return-0-dentro-de-la-funci%c3%b3n-main) para saber más del tema.

   ```
   int main() {

      ...

      return 0;
   }
   ```

### Consejo.

No es práctico repetir funciones para que hagan lo mismo, en su lugar usa plantillas:

```
class sumar{
public:
    template <typename ... TIPOS>
    auto suma(TIPOS ... valores)
    {
         return (valores + ...);
    }
};
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZFPa8IwGIfPyad4cZfWamzrYKDOy047TahHYWTxXQk0ScmfwRC/@rqYlZ3UW/jlfZ78koi@n4uO63YYHqQWXTgibKRx3iJXWxqc1C1ortD1XCA4f1xTGgHnwAXF7Yn24aOTYkWJR9V33Efef/d4YYAxBvvX3VuzpYQHbxKTpSTtffHOWHQ5JSdKCFj0wWrIxhiKNFRAma8pOdNzPFpqD4pLneUQkVQBlHy/LOLMYgo7KxXGDI03RwPTBSXCBA@bDUwO@qCbOAnVCiaXZCRZqlXN6vzP0WAbdIQVXnMkQ33DMFuOjj1akXrcVCyvKZYsStjTKHkJ3Pq7PR7vSGZVyer8/@aT@HxkfOJyTc/D8CM@O966YR6/9VkURc1/AQ)</kbd>.