# Pedir nombre y grupo de n alumnos y acomodar los nombres por grupo

Tags: c++, array, punteros

Estoy empezando con esto de la programación por lo que pido disculpas si aun soy un poco ignorante en estas cosas. Tengo que hacer un programa que pregunte el nombre y grupo del alumno para al final acomodarlos por grupo en forma de lista.  Ya he intentado de todo, pero al final el programa solo me lee los nombres y grupos pero al final no me crea la lista.
Este es un avance de lo que llevo hecho:

```
#include <iostream> 

#include <stdio.h> 

#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;

    string* nombre= NULL;

    string* grupo= NULL;

    int alumnos;

    cout<<"Cantidad de alumnos: "; 

    string entrada;

    getline(cin,entrada);

    alumnos=stoi(entrada);

    nombre= new string[alumnos];

    grupo= new string[alumnos];

    for(int i=0; i<=alumnos; i++) {

        cout<<"Grupo Del Alumno: ";
        getline (cin, grupo[i]);

        if( grupo[i] == "a" ){
            cout<<"\nNombre Del Alumno: ";
            getline (cin, nombre[i]);
            a=a+1;
        }
    }
    for(int i=1; i<=a; i++){

        cout<<i<<". "<<nombre[i]<<endl;
    }
    delete [] nombre;
    delete [] grupo;
    nombre = NULL;
    grupo = NULL;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar, te damos la bienvenida al mundo de la programación; te animo a que sigas haciendo más preguntas.

Por lo que puedo ver en tu código no estás creando ninguna lista en ningún sitio. Lo que sí haces es crear en memoria dinámica<sup>1</sup> dos arreglos de tamaño `alumnos` a los que posteriormente asignas valores; esto no es que sea incorrecto, simplemente no se ajusta a tu enunciado:

> programa que pregunte el nombre y grupo del alumno para al final acomodarlos por grupo en forma de lista

Tal y como has redactado el código, tienes un grupo por alumno y un alumno por grupo. Lo que en realidad querías usar era un [contenedor asociativo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_containers) combinado con otro contenedor, te aconsejo usar un mapa (`std::map`) porque agrupa elementos por clave y una lista (`std::list`). Con esos consejos tu código podría parecerse a:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <map>
#include <list>

int main()
{
    // Procura usar 'using namespace std' en ámbitos cerrados.
    using namespace std;

    int alumnos;
    cout << "Cantidad de alumnos: ";
    // Puedes leer directamente el número.
    cin >> alumnos;
    // Al leer numeros, el salto de línea se queda en el buffer, lo ignoramos.
    cin.ignore();

    // Los alias hacen el código más legible.

    // Alias al tipo de lista de alumnos:
    using alumnos_t = list<string>;
    // Alias al tipo de grupos de alumnos:
    using grupos_t = map<string, alumnos_t>;

    string grupo, nombre;
    grupos_t grupos;

    // Evita los nombres de una sola letra, pueden ser confusos
    for (int id_alumno = 0; id_alumno != alumnos; ++id_alumno)
    {
        cout << "Grupo Del Alumno: ";
        getline(cin, grupo);

        /* Insertamos en el grupo 'grupo' una lista vacia
        si el grupo ya tenia elementos, no inserta nada.

        - En 'posicion' ira a parar una iterador
          apuntando al grupo 'grupo'.
        - En 'insertado' irá a parar el resultado de
          la insercion 'true' si el grupo era nuevo,
          'false' si el grupo ya existía. */
        auto [posicion, insertado] = grupos.insert({grupo, {}});

        cout << "\nNombre Del Alumno: ";
        getline(cin, nombre);
        // El segundo elemento ('second') del iterador, es la lista de alumnos.
        posicion->second.push_back(nombre);
    }

    // Ahora mostramos los alumnos agrupados:
    for (const auto &[grupo, lista] : grupos)
    {
        cout << "\nAlumnos del grupo " << grupo << '\n';
        for (const auto &alumno : lista)
            cout << '\t' << alumno << '\n';
    }


    // No olvides devolver un valor al finalizar 'main'
    // https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/139716/2742
    return 0;
}
```

Si te fijas, no ha sido necesario gestionar memoria dinámica porque los contenedores se encargan de ello.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>¡Genial! no has olvidado liberar dicha memoria al finalizar usando `delete[]`, eso es algo que muchos principiantes olvidan.</sup>