# make c++ referencia sin definir libreria ntl

Tags: c++, makefile, enlace, make

Estoy intentando ejecutar una pequeña prueba con la librería **HELib**, la descarge de aquí [Helib](https://github.com/shaih/HElib)

Concretamente esta explicada aquí [Tutorial](https://pwnhome.wordpress.com/2013/06/19/guide-to-helib-3/)

He seguido los pasos correctamente para instalar las librerías necesarias. El problema se da a la hora de hacer `make HEcalc`, como soy nueva en esto de `c++` no sé solucionarlo.

Esto es lo que obtengo:

> usuario@debian-9:~/Descargas/HEcalc$ make HEcalc 
>   g++ -g -O2 -Wfatal-errors -Wshadow -Wall -I/usr/local/include -o HEcalc -I/home/usuario/Descargas/HElib-master/src HEcalc.cpp -L/usr/local/lib /home/usuario/Descargas/HElib-master/src/fhe.a -lntl -lgmp -lm
>   /usr/local/lib/libntl.a(ZZ_pX1.o): En la función `NTL::ZZ* NTL::details_pthread::key_wrapper::set<NTL::ZZ>(NTL::ZZ*)':
>   /home/usuario/Descargas/ntl-11.0.0/ntl-11.0.0/src/../include/NTL/tools.h:664: referencia a`pthread_setspecific' sin definir
>   /home/usuario/Descargas/ntl-11.0.0/ntl-11.0.0/src/../include/NTL/tools.h:664: referencia a `pthread_setspecific' sin definir
>   /home/usuario/Descargas/ntl-11.0.0/ntl-11.0.0/src/../include/NTL/tools.h:664: referencia a`pthread_setspecific' sin definir
>   /usr/local/lib/libntl.a(ZZ_pX1.o): En la función `NTL::details_pthread::key_wrapper::key_wrapper(void (*)(void*))':
>   /home/usuario/Descargas/ntl-11.0.0/ntl-11.0.0/src/../include/NTL/tools.h:656: referencia a`pthread_key_create' sin definir
>   /usr/local/lib/libntl.a(ZZ_pX1.o): En la función `NTL::ZZ* NTL::details_pthread::key_wrapper::set<NTL::ZZ>(NTL::ZZ*)':
>   /home/usuario/Descargas/ntl-11.0.0/ntl-11.0.0/src/../include/NTL/tools.h:664: referencia a`pthread_setspecific' sin definir
>   /usr/local/lib/libntl.a(ZZ_pX1.o): En la función `NTL::details_pthread::key_wrapper::key_wrapper(void (*)(void*))':
>   /home/usuario/Descargas/ntl-11.0.0/ntl-11.0.0/src/../include/NTL/tools.h:656: referencia a`pthread_key_create' sin definir
>   /usr/local/lib/libntl.a(ZZ_pX1.o): En la función `NTL::ZZ* NTL::details_pthread::key_wrapper::set<NTL::ZZ>(NTL::ZZ*)':
>   /home/usuario/Descargas/ntl-11.0.0/ntl-11.0.0/src/../include/NTL/tools.h:664: referencia a`pthread_setspecific' sin definir
>   /usr/local/lib/libntl.a(mat_ZZ_p.o): En la función `NTL::ZZ_p* NTL::details_pthread::key_wrapper::set<NTL::ZZ_p>(NTL::ZZ_p*)':
>   /home/usuario/Descargas/ntl-11.0.0/ntl-11.0.0/src/../include/NTL/tools.h:664: referencia a`pthread_setspecific' sin definir
>   /home/usuario/Descargas/ntl-11.0.0/ntl-11.0.0/src/../include/NTL/tools.h:664: referencia a `pthread_setspecific' sin definir
>   /usr/local/lib/libntl.a(FFT.o): En la función`NTL::Vec >* NTL::details_pthread::key_wrapper::set > >(NTL::Vec >*)':
>   /home/usuario/Descargas/ntl-11.0.0/ntl-11.0.0/src/../include/NTL/tools.h:664: referencia a `pthread_setspecific' sin definir
>   /usr/local/lib/libntl.a(FFT.o): En la función`NTL::details_pthread::key_wrapper::key_wrapper(void (*)(void*))':
>   /home/usuario/Descargas/ntl-11.0.0/ntl-11.0.0/src/../include/NTL/tools.h:656: referencia a `pthread_key_create' sin definir
>   /usr/local/lib/libntl.a(FFT.o): En la función`NTL::Vec >* NTL::details_pthread::key_wrapper::set > >(NTL::Vec >*)':
>   /home/usuario/Descargas/ntl-11.0.0/ntl-11.0.0/src/../include/NTL/tools.h:664: referencia a `pthread_setspecific' sin definir
>   ......
>   ..... muchas líneas similares
>   ......
>   ......
>   /usr/local/lib/libntl.a(quad_float.o): En la función`NTL::RR* NTL::details_pthread::key_wrapper::set(NTL::RR*)':
>   /home/usuario/Descargas/ntl-11.0.0/ntl-11.0.0/src/../include/NTL/tools.h:664: referencia a `pthread_setspecific' sin definir
>   /usr/local/lib/libntl.a(quad_float.o): En la función`NTL::details_pthread::key_wrapper::key_wrapper(void (*)(void*))':
>   /home/usuario/Descargas/ntl-11.0.0/ntl-11.0.0/src/../include/NTL/tools.h:656: referencia a `pthread_key_create' sin definir
>   /usr/local/lib/libntl.a(quad_float.o): En la función`NTL::RR* NTL::details_pthread::key_wrapper::set(NTL::RR*)':
>   /home/usuario/Descargas/ntl-11.0.0/ntl-11.0.0/src/../include/NTL/tools.h:664: referencia a `pthread_setspecific' sin definir
>   /usr/local/lib/libntl.a(quad_float.o): En la función`NTL::details_pthread::key_wrapper::key_wrapper(void (*)(void*))':
>   /home/usuario/Descargas/ntl-11.0.0/ntl-11.0.0/src/../include/NTL/tools.h:656: referencia a `pthread_key_create' sin definir
>   /usr/local/lib/libntl.a(quad_float.o): En la función`NTL::RR* NTL::details_pthread::key_wrapper::set(NTL::RR*)':
>   /home/usuario/Descargas/ntl-11.0.0/ntl-11.0.0/src/../include/NTL/tools.h:664: referencia a `pthread_setspecific' sin definir
>   /usr/local/lib/libntl.a(quad_float.o): En la función`NTL::details_pthread::key_wrapper::key_wrapper(void (*)(void*))':
>   /home/usuario/Descargas/ntl-11.0.0/ntl-11.0.0/src/../include/NTL/tools.h:656: referencia a `pthread_key_create' sin definir
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   Makefile:11: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'HEcalc'
>   make: *** [HEcalc] Error 1

Supongo que el problema está al linkear las librerías, pero como ya he dicho soy nueva y no sé qué ocurre...

¿Algunda idea?

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Simbolo externo sin resolver ¿Qué he hecho mal?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/65557/simbolo-externo-sin-resolver-qu%c3%a9-he-hecho-mal)

Comment: Esta solución no resuelve mi problema...

Comment: Sin embargo, es el problema que estás encontrando: no te enlazan (linkan) partes del código.

Comment: Finalmente era una tontería, me faltaba añadir -pthread a las librerías en el Makefile.