# Error al llamar a una funcion en c

Tags: c, linux, funciones, gcc, makefile

Tengo el archivo .c con la funcion que quiero invocar

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "entrada_minishell.h"

void imprimir_prompt()
{
   printf("minishell> "); 
   fflush(stdout);        
}
void leer_linea_ordenes(char *buf)
{

   memset(buf, 0, sizeof(BUFSIZ));

   if (fgets(buf, BUFSIZ-1, stdin) == NULL) /* fgets almacena la orden leída introduciendo también el carácter de fin de línea */
   { 
      buf[0] = '\0';
      return;
   }

   eliminar_salto_linea(buf);  
}
```

y su archivo .h

```
#ifndef ENTRADA_MINISHELL_H
#define ENTRADA_MINISHELL_H

void leer_linea_ordenes(char *cad);
void imprimir_prompt();

#endif
```

cuando quiero invocar la funcion desde otro archivo llamado minishell.c con el main()

```
  #include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "internas.h"
#include "entrada_minishell.h"
#include "ejecutar.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

   char buf[BUFSIZ];

   while (1)
   {
    imprimir_prompt();   
    leer_linea_ordenes(buf);

    if (strcmp(buf,"exit")==0){
        break;   
    }   

    else   
    {   
        if(es_ord_interna(buf)){
            ejecutar_ord_interna(buf);   
        }
        else{
            ejecutar_linea_ordenes(buf);
        }
     }  
   }

   return 0;    

}
```

me da este error: `En la función 'main':/home/.../minishell.c:24: referencia a 'imprimir_prompt' sin definir`

para compilarlo

```
CFLAGS= gcc -Wall -g

minishell: minishell.o entrada_minishell.o 
    gcc -Wall -g minishell.o entrada_minishell.o  -o  minishell 

entrada_minishell.o: entrada_minishell.c entrada_minishell.h
    $(CFLAGS) entrada_minishell.c -o entrada_minishell.o

minishell.o: minishell.c  
    $(CFLAGS) minishell.c -o minishell.o
```

Comment: Las dos funciones estan definidas, pero no habia añadido la declaracion de la segunda porque no me da error, ahora esta actualizado

Comment: Léete la respuesta completa, a partir de la *Explicación*. Así entenderás el problema y como solucionarlo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/65558/19610

Comment: @abulafia ¿ Porqué no pones tu comentario como respuesta, con el Makefile correcto ?

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en el `Makefile`.

Cuando compilas un `.c` con la intención de crear un `.o`, debes pasar al compilador la opción `-c`, por ejemplo así:

```
gcc -c minishell.c
```

Puedes omitir en este caso el `-o minishell.o`, ya que por defecto creará un objeto con el mismo nombre que el fuente.

Sin la opción `-c`, `gcc` ejecutará en secuencia dos pasos: primero la compilación (que no daría errores en tu caso) y después el enlazado para crear un ejecutable (que en tu caso llevaría el nombre, erróneo, `minishell.o`, y no puede ser creado porque faltan funciones). No quieres que intente crear un ejecutable, sino que haga sólo la fase de compilación. Para eso es la opción `-c`.

Otro detalle, que no tiene relevancia para el error que comentas, pero que conviene hacer bien, es que `CFLAGS` se usa normalmente para contener las opciones de compilación, pero no el propio nombre del compilador que suele guardarse en cambio en la variable `CC`.

Por tanto, un `Makefile` más correcto sería:

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -g
CC=gcc

minishell: minishell.o entrada_minishell.o 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) minishell.o entrada_minishell.o  -o  minishell 

entrada_minishell.o: entrada_minishell.c entrada_minishell.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c entrada_minishell.c

minishell.o: minishell.c  
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c minishell.c
```

De hecho, puedes omitir el comando en todas tus reglas, ya, gracias a sus [reglas implícitas](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules), `make` conoce qué comando ha de ejecutar por defecto para crear un `.o` a partir de un `.c`, o un ejecutable a partir de varios `.o`. Basta por tanto que especifiques las dependencias y él deducirá el resto:

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -g
CC=gcc

minishell: minishell.o entrada_minishell.o 

entrada_minishell.o: entrada_minishell.c entrada_minishell.h

minishell.o: minishell.c
```