# C++ error LNK2019 Unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++

Tengo un error y no se como resolverlo, informcion extra es: Visual studio 2017, en un empty project.

> LNK2019   unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl
>   Biseccion::inicio(void)" (?inicio@Biseccion@@SAXXZ) referenced in
>   function _main

Source.cpp:

```
#include "Biseccion.h"
using namespace std;
int main() {
    //Biseccion * bi = new Biseccion();
    Biseccion bi;
    bi.inicio();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Biseccion.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include "Ecuacion.h"

using namespace std;
class Biseccion {
public:
    static void inicio(void);
    Biseccion(void);
};
```

Biseccion.cpp:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include "Ecuacion.h"

using namespace std;
class Biseccion {
private:
    int longitudEcua = 0;
    Ecuacion * ecuat;
    vector<double> * preguntarArray() {
//codigo del metodo
        return &ecu;
    }

public:
    void inicio(void) {
//Codigo del metodo
    }
    Biseccion();
};

Biseccion::Biseccion() { ; }
```

Ecuacion.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
class Ecuacion {
public:
    void setEcua(vector<double> * s);
    vector<double>* getEcua(void);
    Ecuacion(int);
    double getPosicion(int x);
    void setPosicion(int x, double val);
    double calculaEcua(double x);
};
```

Ecuacion.cpp:

```
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
class Ecuacion {
private:
    int siseX;
    vector<double>  ecua;
public:

    void setEcua(vector<double> * s) { ecua = *s; };
    vector<double>* getEcua() { return &ecua; }
    Ecuacion(int);

    double getPosicion(int x) {
        return ecua.at(x);
    };
    void setPosicion(int x, double val) {
        ecua.insert(ecua.begin() + x, val);
    }
    double calculaEcua(double x) {
//codigo del metodo
};

Ecuacion::Ecuacion(int x) {
//constructor
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**En C++ no es necesario usar `void` como parámetro**

En C, si no le ponemos `void` a una función que no recibe parámetros la misma podrá recibir un número indeterminado de ellos:

```
void func1();     // func admite parametros: func1(1,2,3,4,5);
void func2(void); // func2 NO admite parametros. solo func2() es llamada valida
```

Sin embargo en C++ no es así. Si una función no tiene parámetros, **no** admitirá parámetros. Así que dado que `void` sobra, no lo uses. Dejarás el código más limpio.

```
// Evitar esto
class Biseccion {
public:
    static void inicio(void);
    Biseccion(void);
};

// Mejor asi
class Biseccion {
public:
    static void inicio();
    Biseccion();
};
```

**No uses `using namespace` en los archivos de cabecera**

Más información aquí: [¿Por qué el usar "using namespace std;" se considera mala práctica?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/460/463)

**La declaración de cada clase debe ser única**

El código que muestras actualmente tiene dos declaraciones de cada clase:

Biseccion.h:

```
using namespace std;
class Biseccion { // <<--- DECLARACION
public:
    static void inicio(void);
    Biseccion(void);
};
```

Biseccion.cpp:

```
class Biseccion { // <<--- DECLARACION
private:
    int longitudEcua = 0;
    Ecuacion * ecuat;
    vector<double> * preguntarArray() {
//codigo del metodo
        return &ecu;
    }
```

Y lamento informarte de que eso no va a funcionar en la vida. La declaración de una clase debe ser única, es decir, solo puedes tener una en todo el programa. Además, esa declaración debe ser **completa**, es decir, debe incluir **todas** las variables y funciones de la clase.

El motivo es bien simple: El compilador necesita conocer, desde el principio, los requisitos de una clase (tamaño en memoria, ubicación de cada variable, funciones que sean estáticas, constructores disponibles, ...).

Usando como muestra la clase `Biseccion`, su disposición podría ser la siguiente:

Biseccion.h

```
class Biseccion {
private:
    int longitudEcua = 0;
    Ecuacion * ecuat;

    vector<double> * preguntarArray();

public:
    void inicio();
    Biseccion();
};
```

Biseccion.cpp

```
#include "Biseccion.h"

Biseccion::Biseccion()
{ /* ... */ }

void Biseccion::inicio()
{ /* ... */ }

vector<double>* preguntarArray()
{ /* ... */ } // <<--- ecu no existe
```

Answer (score 1):

El enlazador te está diciendo que has declarado la función `static void Biseccion::inicio(void)`, pero no la has definido, puedes ver más detalles en [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/65557/2742).

---

En tu cabecera (`.h`) declaras la función como estática:

```
class Biseccion {
public:
    static void inicio(void); // Estática
    Biseccion(void);
};
```

En tu archivo de código (`.cpp`) defines la función como miembro:

```
class Biseccion {
private:
    int longitudEcua = 0;
    Ecuacion * ecuat;
    vector<double> * preguntarArray() {
//codigo del metodo
        return &ecu;
    }

public:
    void inicio(void) { // Función miembro, ¡no función estática!
//Codigo del metodo
    }
    Biseccion();
};
```

Para el compilador la versión estática y la versión miembro son funciones diferentes, así que tienes una función `static void Biseccion::inicio(void)` declarada pero no existe la parte definida.

Para solucionarlo, sigue los excelentes consejos de [eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/208119/2742) y marca la definición también como estática.