# ¿Cómo resuelvo el error "Id returned 1 exit status"?

Tags: c++, c, compilar

El programa compilaba más o menos sin problemas pero de repente me salió este error y no sé cómo solucionarlo. El programa no está acabado del todo, aun me queda solucionar errores en los resultados de operaciones pero eso no debería ser el problema(¿no?).

[image: Error de compilacion]

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define TAM 1000
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

int menu(){
    int op;
    do{

        printf("--------------- Menu de opciones ---------------\n\n");
        printf("1. Consulta de un compuesto\n\n2. Compuestos con mejor y peor balance.\n\n3. Compuestos de bajo rendimiento.\n\n");
        printf("4. Generar balances positivos y negativos.\n\n0. Terminar.\n\n");
        printf("------------------------------------------------\n\nElige una opcion (0-4) :\n");
        scanf("%d", &op);
        if(op<0 || op>4){ printf("Opcion incorrecta, vuelva a elegir.\n\n"); system("PAUSE"); system("cls");}
    }while(op<0 || op>4);
return op;
}


int leer_datos(float ingresos[TAM], float costesProd[TAM], float costesDist[TAM]){
    int i, n;
    float in, pr, di;
    FILE *f1;

    for(i=0;i<TAM;i++){
        ingresos[i]=0;
        costesProd[i]=0;
        costesDist[i]=0;
    }

    f1=fopen("compuestos.txt", "r");
    if(f1==NULL){fclose(f1); return -1;}
    while(fscanf(f1, "%d%f%f%f" ,&n, &in, &pr, &di)!=EOF){
        ingresos[n]=in;
        costesProd[n]=pr;
        costesDist[n]=di;
    }
    fclose(f1);
    return 0;
}


void consulta_compuesto(float ingresos[TAM], float costesProd[TAM], float costesDist[TAM]){
    int x;

    printf("Codigo del compesto: \n");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    if(x>=0 && x<=999){
        if(ingresos[x]==0){
        printf("\n\nCompuesto no disponible\n\n");
        system("PAUSE");
        }
        else{
            printf("\nIngresos: %.2f\n\nCostes de produccion: %.2f\n\nCostes de distribucion: %.2f\n\n", ingresos[x], costesProd[x], costesDist[x]);
            printf("BALANCE: %.2f\n\n\n\n", ingresos[x]-costesProd[x]-costesDist[x]);
            system("PAUSE");    
            }
    }
    else{printf("\n\nCodigo no valido\n\n"); system("PAUSE");}
}


void compuestos_mejor_peor(float ingresos[TAM], float costesProd[TAM], float costesDist[TAM],int *mej, int *per){
    int i=0;
    float bmej, bper;
    *mej=ingresos[i]-(costesProd[i]-costesDist[i]);
    *per=ingresos[i]-(costesProd[i]-costesDist[i]);

    for(i=0;i<TAM;i++){
        if(ingresos[i]-(costesProd[i]-costesDist[i])>*mej) *mej=i;
        if(ingresos[i]-(costesProd[i]-costesDist[i])<*per) *per=i;
    }
}


void compuestos_bajo_rendimiento(float ingresos[TAM], float costesProd[TAM], float costesDist[TAM]){
    int i, k=0;
    float media, m=0, md;

    for(i=0;i<TAM;i++){
    m+=ingresos[i];
    if(ingresos[i]!=0) k++; 
    }
    media=m/k;
    md=media*0.1;
    printf("Compuestos de bajo rendimiento:\n\n");
    for(i=0;i<TAM;i++){
        if(ingresos[i]<md && costesDist[i]>costesProd[i]){
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }
    system("PAUSE");
}


int generar_balances(float ingresos[TAM], float costesProd[TAM], float costesDist[TAM]){
    int i;
    FILE *fpos, *fneg;

    fpos=fopen("pos.txt", "w");
    if(fpos==NULL) return -1;
    fneg=fopen("neg.txt", "w");
    if(fneg==NULL) return -1;

    for(i=0;i<TAM;i++){
        if(ingresos[i]-(costesProd[i]-costesDist[i])>0){
            fprintf(fpos,"%d (%f euros)\n", i, ingresos[i]-(costesProd[i]-costesDist[i]));
            }
        else fprintf(fneg,"%d (%f euros)\n", i, ingresos[i]-(costesProd[i]-costesDist[i]));     
    }
    fclose(fpos);
    fclose(fneg);
return 0;
}



int main(){
    int op, e, mej=0, per=0, r;
    float ingresos[TAM], costesProd[TAM], costesDist[TAM];

    e=leer_datos(ingresos, costesProd, costesDist);
    if(e==-1){printf("Error a leer el fichero"); return 0;}
    do{
        op=menu();
        switch(op){
            case 1: consulta_compuesto(ingresos, costesProd, costesDist);
                    break;
            case 2: compuestos_mejor_peor(ingresos, costesProd, costesDist, &mej, &per);
                    printf("\n\nCompuesto con mejor balance: %d (%.2f euros)\n\n", mej, ingresos[mej]-costesDist[mej]-costesProd[mej]);
                    printf("Compuesto con peor balance: %d (%.2f euros)\n\n", per, ingresos[per]-costesDist[per]-costesProd[per]);

                    break;
            case 3: compuestos_bajo_rendimiento(ingresos, costesProd, costesDist);
                    break;
            case 4: r = generar_balances(ingresos, costesProd, costesDist);
                    if(r==-1){
                        printf("ERROR creando fichero neg.txt\n\n");
                    }
                    else {printf("Los ficheros se han creado correctamente.\n\n");}
                    break;  
        }
    }while(op!=0);
return 0;
}
```

Creo que el problema puede estar en la función generar_balances(), pero no estoy muy seguro.

Comment: Justo antes de la línea del error `ld` tienes otra en que te explica la razón. No puede crear el archivo `.exe` porque no puede escribir en él. Lo más probable es que tengas ese programa en ejecución, en alguna otra ventana.

Comment: ese error es producido cuando intentas guardar y ejecutar el codigo desde el disco local (C:) al ser esta una aplicación que no tiene permisos de administrador para acceder a ese espacio produce ese error, te sugiero guarda tu codigo en otro lado que no sea el disco(C:)

Comment: pues a mi cuando me sale ese mensaje en ocasiones lo soluciono guardando el proyecto con un nuevo nombre.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Simbolo externo sin resolver ¿Qué he hecho mal?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/65557/simbolo-externo-sin-resolver-qu%c3%a9-he-hecho-mal)

Comment: En la ventana de compilación aparece que tiene (2) elementos

Comment: Estimado, acabo de tener el mismo problema, para mi caso en particular resultó que no me fijé que el proceso ya estaba siendo ejecutado, pese a estar abierto, intenté compilar nuevamente. tener en cuenta eso.

Comment: asegúrate que no tienes una instancia corriendo del programa, si lo corriste y no lo cerraste y luego intentas guardarlo y compilarlo así, te saltara ese error. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Si te fijas en la parte de abajo del programa (la salida o output) nos dice el error que has puesto, pero si te fijas más arriba sale lo que ha intentado hacer cuando se ha producido error. Esto se debe a que no has abierto DEV-C++ con permisos de administrado ya que no puede abrir el archivo porque no tiene permisos.

También te digo he copiado el programa en mi IDE y salta un error de Core dumped que seguramente se este saliendo de algún vector. Esa parte te la dejo a ti.

Answer (score -1):

compilando en Qt tuve un error similar, se arreglaba al eliminar de la carpeta del proyecto unos ficheros con extension `.user`, quizá te resuelva, a veces ese error se provocaba por mover el proyecto de ubicación.

Te aconsejo que guardes el proyecto antes de eliminar ningun fichero, y luego busques a ver si hay algun fichero de configuracion de usuario o algo parecido que pueda estar dando este error