# LInked error, undefined reference to 'vtable for figura'

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

class figura{
   protected: 
    string nombre;
    int lados;
   public:
    virtual int area();    

};

class cuadrado:public figura{

    public:
        cuadrado(){
        lados=4;
    }
    virtual int area(){
    return lados*lados;
    }
};

class triangulo:public figura{
    int a,b;
    public:
        triangulo(){
        lados=3;
    }
    void pedir(){
    cout<<"Base: "<<endl;
    cin>>b;
    cout<<"Altura: "<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    }
    virtual int area(){
    return ((b*a)/(2));
    }
};



main(){
    int op;
    int *punt;
    int v;
    cout<<"FIGURAS"<<endl;
    cout<<"1. Cuadrado\n2. Triangulo"<<endl;
    cin>>op;
    if(op==1){
        cuadrado ob1;
        v=ob1.area();
        punt=&v;
    }
    else{
        triangulo ob1;
        ob1.pedir();
        ob1.area();
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema está aquí:

```
class figura {
...
public:
  virtual int area( );
};
```

Declaras tu función-miembro como `virtual`, pero **no tienes** el *cuerpo* de la función, ni la has declarado como *virtual pura*.

El compilador, cuando encuentra una función-miembro `virtual`, tiene libertad para implementarla *a su gusto*; la mayoría (por no decir todos) usan un mecanimo, *VPTR + VTABLE*.

Digamos que consiste en *añadir* un puntero *oculto* a tu clase, que contiene la dirección de las funciones virtuales de la misma; sería algo así:

```
// El compilador general algo como esto

class figura;

struct figuraVTABLE {
  int ( *area )( figura *this );
};

class figura {
  struct figuraVTABLE *VPTR;
  ...
  // Las cosas reales de tu clase ...
  ...
};
```

Eso es un mecanismo *oculto* y *transparente* para tí; no es necesario que trates con ello. El compilador se encarga de eso sin que tú tengas siquiera que saberlo.

Además de lo anterior, C++ trabaja con *unidades de traducción* individuales: está permitido declarar *cosas* en un archivo e *implementarlas* en otro. Es el motivo de la existencia de *archivos de cabecera*, y de que la generación de un ejecutable se realice en 2 pasos: **compilación** + **enlazado**.

¿ El problema de todo esto ? Pues que puedes declarar cosas en un sitio, y *olvidar* darles un valor ... que es lo que te está pasando.

Al declarar una función-miembro como `virtual`, el compilador añade una variable a tu clase, pero **no le asigna ningún valor**; es el enlazador el que se encarga de eso. Y ya sabemos que ese valor puede estar en otra *unidad de traducción*.

Ese es tu problema: el `VPTR` de tu clase **no se corresponde** con ninguna `VTABLE`.

Tienes 2 soluciones:

1. Declara tu función-miembro como *pura*:

   ```
   class figura {
   ...
   public:
     virtual int area( ) = 0; // <- AQUÍ
   };
   ```

   Con eso, **ya estás inicializando tu `VPTR`**. Informas de que esa función-miembro **no tiene cuerpo**. Tu clase pasa a ser *abstracta*, con lo que **no puedes** declarar variables instancias de esa clase:

   ```
   figura mifigura1; // <-- ERROR.
   ```
2. Implementa tu función-miembro; ponle un *cuerpo*.
   Esto se puede hacer en un archivo aparte y que luego el enlazador se encargue:

   ```
   // firgura.cpp
   int figura::area( ) {
   ...
   }
   ```

   O puedes hacerlo todo en un mismo archivo:

   ```
   class figura {
   ...
   public:
     virtual int area( ) {
       ...
     }
   };
   ```

<sub>**Nota**: esto declara tu función-miembro como `inline`, lo cual es una historia aparte ... pero ya nos estamos extendiendo demasiado.</sub>

En tu caso concreto, creo que la solución que buscas es la `1`: convertir tu clase en una *clase abstracta*.

<sub>**Nota**: Tu problema es una variación de [Símbolo externo sin resolver. ¿ Qué he hecho mal ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/65558/19610)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Todo tu problema se puede resumir en el siguiente código:

```
struct B
{
    virtual void f();
};

struct D : B
{};

int main()
{
    D{}.f();
    return 0;
}
```

El error completo sería:

> ```
> undefined reference to `B::f()'
> In function `B::B()':
> undefined reference to `vtable for B'
> undefined reference to `B::f()'
> ```

Es claro y autoexplicativo, pero lo traduzco para que lo sea aún más:

> ```
> referencia a `B::f()' no definida
> En la función `B::B()':
> referencia a `vtable for B' no definida
> referencia a `B::f()' no definida
> ```

El error nos ha dicho tres veces que la función `f` de `B` no está definida, y es cierto, está sólo declarada, así que para que el error desaparezca debes definir la función `area` de `figura`:

```
class figura {
protected: 
    string nombre;
    int lados;
public:
    virtual int area() { return {}; }
};
```

Pero en vista de que cada una de las figuras derivadas van a sobrescribir la función `area`, no tiene sentido que ésta tenga definición, podrías evitar definirla haciéndola [virtual pura](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funci%C3%B3n_virtual#C++):

```
class figura {
protected: 
    string nombre;
    int lados;
public:
    virtual int area() = 0;
};
```

Esta solución, además de tener la ventaja de no escribir código que no tiene sentido que sea escrito, te obliga a definir la función en las clases derivadas y provoca error de compilación en caso de que se te olvide hacerlo.