# no se volvio a repetir el mismo error

Tags: c, gcc, ld

un saludos esto me aparecio cuando intente compilar mi codigo en c

```
[fedora@localhost run]$ ./get\ objects.sh 
[fedora@localhost run]$ ./compile.sh 
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cceIPjy5.o: in function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `add'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x70): undefined reference to `add'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x9f): undefined reference to `contains'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0xb6): undefined reference to `contains'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0xd7): undefined reference to `contains'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0xf8): undefined reference to `add'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x10a): undefined reference to `differ'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x12b): undefined reference to `drop'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x13d): undefined reference to `contains'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x15e): undefined reference to `drop'
/usr/bin/ld: main.c:(.text+0x179): undefined reference to `drop'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

hasta aqui todo mi codigo me habia arrojado este formato de advetencia de funcion sin definir pero al crear la funcion add me aparece este formato:

```
[fedora@localhost run]$ ./get\ objects.sh 
[fedora@localhost run]$ ./compile.sh 
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccqthU5I.o: in function `main':
/home/fedora/aqui.programacion/pooc/run/../src/main.c:16: undefined reference to `contains'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/fedora/aqui.programacion/pooc/run/../src/main.c:17: undefined reference to `contains'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/fedora/aqui.programacion/pooc/run/../src/main.c:20: undefined reference to `contains'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/fedora/aqui.programacion/pooc/run/../src/main.c:23: undefined reference to `differ'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/fedora/aqui.programacion/pooc/run/../src/main.c:26: undefined reference to `drop'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/fedora/aqui.programacion/pooc/run/../src/main.c:26: undefined reference to `contains'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/fedora/aqui.programacion/pooc/run/../src/main.c:29: undefined reference to `drop'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/fedora/aqui.programacion/pooc/run/../src/main.c:30: undefined reference to `drop'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

pero al eliminar la funcion add queda este mismo fromato para la advertencia de funciones sin definir y no ha regresado al formato anterior con que me desplegaba.

Intentos que he realizado:

reiniciar el pc
eliminar todas las {rm -Rf /tmp/*}
cerrar la terminal abrirla de nuevo.

indistintamente del orden en que realize estos procedimientos.

Gracias por comentar un saludos enorme.
P.D. (gcc) 10.0.1

Comment: Cuál es el código que genera esta salida al compilar? Añádelo a tu pregunta, por favor

Comment: Eso no son errores de compilación. Son errores del linker y esto se debe porque que no encuentra el contenido de esas funciones. La pregunta es, ¿estás usando alguna biblioteca?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Simbolo externo sin resolver ¿Qué he hecho mal?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/65557/simbolo-externo-sin-resolver-qu%c3%a9-he-hecho-mal)

Comment: El sentido de mi pregunta es que cuando comence a programar me estaba arrojando errores en el linker de este formato en que se los presente cuando satisfice una propiedad ese formato cambio y aunque elimine esa nueva funcion para restaurar o volver a repetir el formato anterior de presentacion de fuentes no satisfechas no se reseteo la presentacion de advertencia de 'fuentes no satisfechas'
Todo el codigo que he escrito no importa lo que quiero es que se fijen en el FORMATO en que el linker me esta dando y que despues no pude volver a replicar ese FORMATO aunque elimine las funciones