# unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, c, funciones, librería

Holaaa, estoy intentando crear una librería pero al momento de compilar me dice "unresolved external symbol" en la función "printObject" he investigado un poco, y he encontrado que se debe a que esta declarada pero no definida, pero realmente no se si es problema con la conexión o alguna declaración que deberia estar haciendo.

```
//JSON.h
#pragma once
namespace JSON{
    struct Object {
        int n;
        char** name;
        char** value;
    };
    void printObject(Object object);
}
```

```
//JSON.cpp
#include "JSON.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
namespace JSON {
    void printObject(Object object) {
        cout << '{' << '\n';
        for (size_t i = 0; i < object.n; i++) {
            cout << '\"' << *(object.name + i) << '\"' << ':' << '\"' << *(object.value + i) << '\"';
            if (i+1 != object.n)
                cout << ',';
            cout << '\n';
        }
        cout << '}' << endl;
    }
};
```

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "./Lib/JSON.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    JSON:: Object object;
    object.n = 2;
    object.name = new char*[2];
    object.value = new char*[2];
    *(object.name) = "id";    *(object.name+1) = "name";
    *(object.value) = "123";    *(object.value+1) = "juan";
    JSON::printObject(object);
    return 0;
}
```

`main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl JSON::printObject(struct JSON::Object)" (?printObject@JSON@@YAXUObject@1@@Z) referenced in function _main main.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals`

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Simbolo externo sin resolver ¿Qué he hecho mal?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/65557/simbolo-externo-sin-resolver-qu%c3%a9-he-hecho-mal)

Answer (score 0):

El error te lo está dando el *linker*. Para entender esto debes saber que la compilación de un programa C se hace en dos fases (aunque generalmente ambas fases ocurren en secuencia automáticamente por lo que tú solo tienes que dar un comando).

Las fases son:

1. **Compilación**. En esta fase se convierte el fuente .c en código máquina. Durante esta fase el compilador verifica que los tipos de las variables se usan de forma correcta. También verifica que las llamadas a funciones usan el número apropiado de parámetros y del tipo apropiado. Para poder hacer esa verificación necesita conocer el *prototipo* de la función, y esa es la razón por la que incluye un .h donde figuran esos prototipos. Sin embargo no necesita el código de la función que está siendo llamada.

   El resultado de esta fase es un archivo intemedio (extensión `.o`) que contiene la versión en código máquina de tu programa, pero está aún incompleto porque en los lugares en donde se llaman a funciones simplemente el compilador ha dejado una marca que viene a decir algo como "aquí va una llamada a una función, complétala". El encargado de completar esa llamada es el *linker*.
2. **Enlazado**. Esta es la fase realizada por el *linker*, que busca todas las marcas que el compilador ha dejado con llamadas incompletas, e intenta resolverlas. Para ello debe buscar el código de las funciones que faltan en otros archivos `.o` que se hayan especificado en la línea de comandos, o en bibliotecas externas (también llamadas librerías). Hay una librería en particular que siempre es utilizada, denominada la *Biblioteca estándar C* que contiene el código máquina de funciones típicamente usadas como `printf()`, `scanf()`, `fopen()`, etc.

   Una vez encuentra en algín `.o` o librería extrena el código de las funciones que faltaban, las añade al ejecutable final y completa las llamadas incompletas. El resultado de esta fase es el ejecutable final.

   El linker no es un compilador. De hecho el linker no ve código C, sólo código máquina. Por ello ya no puede realizar comprobaciones de tipos o número de parámetros. Se supone que eso ya lo hizo el compilador.

Cuando compilas algo con `gcc` o `g++` (o el compilador que uses), esos dos pasos ocurren en secuencia, y el fichero `.o` intermedio es borrado, por lo que nunca lo ves.

Sin embargo cuando estás escribiendo código que se compone de varios ficheros, deberás dar estos pasos por separado:

1. Compilar "solo" (sin intentar enlazar) cada uno de los .c que componen tu aplicación, obteniendo una serie de ficheros `.o`. Para que "solo" compile se debe usar la opción `-c`.
2. Enlazar todos los `.o` para crear el ejecutable final.

Esto en tu caso lo harías así:

```
# Compilar por separado cada fuente
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ -c JSON.cpp

# Enlazar ambos en un ejecutable
g++ -o nombre_ejecutable main.o JSON.o
```

Como ves, el *linker* se invoca con el mismo comando que el compilador, pero se le pasan los ficheros `.o`  en vez de los `.c`

Cuando se tienen muchos ficheros a compilar separadamente es habitual escribir un `Makefile` que automatizará la compilación de los que sea necesario (los que hayan sido editados) a la hora de recrear el ejecutable.