# Listar los puertos COM físicos de una PC con C++

Tags: c++, puertos

Estoy trabajando en un programa (con c++ y en windows) que debe recolectar información desde un arduino. La cuestión es que el arduino no siempre va a estar conectado en el mismo puerto COM, por lo que quiero listar los puertos COM y si el dispositivo conectado coincide con el nombre del arduino, realizar las operaciones.

El problema es que no puedo listar los COM. Estuve probando con la función EnumPorts, a continuación dejo la parte del código donde intento listar los COM. Para facilitar la lectura, quite el segmento de captura de errores.

Como resultado obtengo:

> C:\Users(...)ENUMERAR PUERTOS.cpp:(.text+0x7e): undefined reference to `EnumPortsA'
> [Error] ld returned 1 exit status

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<Winspool.h>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    DWORD devueltos,necesarios;
    PPORT_INFO_2    buffer = NULL;

    devueltos = necesarios = 0;

    cout<<"ENUMERANDO PUERTOS: "<<endl;
    EnumPorts(argv[1],1,(LPBYTE)buffer, 0, &necesarios, &devueltos);

    for (int i = 0; i < devueltos; i ++){
        cout<<"Nombre del puerto: "<<buffer[i].pPortName;
        cout<<"Nombre del Monitor: "<<buffer[i].pMonitorName;
        cout<<"Tipo: "<<buffer[i].fPortType;
    }

    free(buffer);

    cout<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Simbolo externo sin resolver ¿Qué he hecho mal?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/65557/simbolo-externo-sin-resolver-qu%c3%a9-he-hecho-mal)

Answer (score 1):

El error sugiere que olvidaste enlazar la librería.

En Visual Studio ve a las propiedades del proyecto (no solución).

Ve a **Linker > Input** y en la propiedad [**Additional Dependencies**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-property-pages?view=msvc-170#input-property-page) agrega la librería [Winspool.lib](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/enumports#requirements).

En la sección **Requirements** de cada función puedes encontrar el encabezado a incluir y la librería a enlazar.

---

Estás usando mal la función.

La documentación dice que si `level` (el segundo parámetro) es 1 espera que `pPorts` (el tercer parámetro) reciba un puntero a un buffer [`PORT_INFO_1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/port-info-1) y si es 2, el puntero debe ser a [`PORT_INFO_2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/port-info-2).

La llamada que haces presenta una contradicción en cuanto a esos 2 parámetros. No puedo ayudarte a decidir cuál quieres usar. Así que supondré que quieres un `PORT_INFO_2`.

También intercambiaste los últimos 2 parámetros.

Arreglando estos puntos, el código se vería así:

```
DWORD puertosDevueltos, bytesNecesarios;
PPORT_INFO_2 buffer = nullptr;

puertosDevueltos = bytesNecesarios = 0;

EnumPorts(argv[1], 2, (LPBYTE)buffer, 0, &bytesNecesarios, &puertosDevueltos);
```