# ¿Cómo se soluciona el error de redefinición en los archivos header?

Tags: c++, headers, g++

Por alguna razón cuando ejecuto un programa c++, las ñ, diéresis, etc no se muestran como deberían, así que hice este header:

```
#ifndef Tildes_h
#define Tildes_h

unsigned char a_con_tilde = 160;
unsigned char a_may_con_tilde = 181;
unsigned char e_con_tilde = 130;
unsigned char e_may_con_tilde = 144;
unsigned char i_con_tilde = 161;
unsigned char i_may_con_tilde = 214;
unsigned char o_con_tilde = 162;
unsigned char o_may_con_tilde = 224;
unsigned char u_con_tilde = 163;
unsigned char u_may_con_tilde = 233;
unsigned char enie =164;
unsigned char enie_may =165;
unsigned char u_con_dieresis = 129;
unsigned char u_may_con_dieresis = 154;
unsigned char numero = 167;

#endif
```

Funciona bien cuando lo uso en un solo archivo:

//  invertebrado.cpp

```
#include "animal.h" // clase base
#include "terrestre.h" //clase derivada de la cual a su vez se derivan las clases en cuestión
#include "invertebrado.h" //una de las clases en las que estoy utilizando el header
#include "tildes.h" // este es el header del problema
```

pero me sale el error de redefinición cuando lo uso en más de un cpp al mismo tiempo:

//  vertebrado.cpp

```
#include "animal.h" // clase base
#include "terrestre.h" //clase derivada de la cual a su vez se derivan las clases en cuestión
#include " vertebrado.h" //otra de las clases en las que estoy utilizando el header
#include "tildes.h" // este es el header del problema
```

multiple definition....... first defined here

he movido el header a los archivos de las clases padre pero no funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#include` copia el contenido del archivo. Todo va a copiarse a cada archivo que lo incluya. Por lo tanto, si dos o más [unidades de traducción](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/65558/169744) lo incluyen, habrá símbolos duplicados.

Por este motivo, habitualmente solo se incluyen los archivos .h, con declaraciones únicamente y las implementaciones se realizan en los archivos .c, que generan una unidad de traducción.

Si te interesa definir *constantes*, puedes hacerlo mediante macros, de esta forma no generas ninguna variable que pueda ser duplicada.

```
#ifndef Tildes_h
#define Tildes_h

#define a_con_tilde 160
#define a_may_con_tilde 181
...

#endif
```

Si no quieres usar macros o necesitas que sean variables, debes marcar las variables como [`extern`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration). Esta palabra clave indica que existe una variable con ese nombre en alguna parte. El linker es el encargado de encontrarla.

En tu archivo **tildes.h**:

```
#ifndef Tildes_h
#define Tildes_h

extern unsigned char a_con_tilde;
extern unsigned char a_may_con_tilde;
...

#endif
```

Y en algún archivo .c, por ejemplo **tildes.c**, defines las variables normalmente:

```
#include "tildes.h"

unsigned char a_con_tilde = 160;
unsigned char a_may_con_tilde = 181;
...
```

Comment: Sí señor, eso lo solucionó, muchas gracias