# problemas con cmath

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo este trabajo de la universidad, y el archivo UI me esta haciendo problemas. Me esta llamando el archivo de librería cmath sin que yo lo hubiera incluido, e intenta convertir un valor float a un objeto UI.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
int UI::readInt(std::string message) {
    int num;
    cout << message << "\n";
    std::cin >> num;
    return num;
}
void UI::write(std::string message) {
    cout << message << "\n";
}
void UI::writeInt(int num) {
    cout << num << " ";
};
```

Tengo incluido la libreria string en el header.

```
#include<string>
class UI {
   public:
       int readInt(std::string);
       void write(std::string);
       void writeInt(int);
}
```

Hice algunas pruebas no pude determinar mas al respecto. Les agradecería mucho la ayuda.
Edit:
Viendo la ventana de salida creo que el archivo operator tiene algo que  ver, dado que ocurre cuando este archivo esta compilando.
Aqui lo paso:

```
#include"operator.h"
#include"ui.h"
#include"logic.h"
void llenar(int vec[], int tam) {
    Logic logic;
    logic.fillArray(vec, tam);
}
void print(int vec[], int tam) {
    UI ui;
    Logic logic;
    ui.write(logic.toString(vec, tam));
}
void sumar(int vec[], int tam) {
    UI ui;
    Logic logic;
    ui.writeInt(logic.sumPairs(vec, tam));
}
void ordenar(int vec[], int tam) {
    Logic logic;
    logic.orderArray(vec, tam);
}
void buscar(int vec[], int tam) {
    UI ui;
    Logic logic;
    int val = ui.readInt("Digite el numero que quiere buscar");
    if (logic.searchValue(val, vec, tam) == true)
        ui.write("El numero si esta en el vector");
    else
        ui.write("El numero no esta en el vector");
}
void moda(int vec[], int tam) {
    UI ui;
    Logic logic;
    ui.writeInt(logic.getMode(vec, tam));
}
void Operator::control() {
    Logic logic;
    UI ui;
    int tamano=10;
    //tamano = ui.readInt("Digite el tamaño del vector");
    int vector[50];
    for (int i = 0; i < tamano; i++)
        vector[i] = 0;
    while (true) {
        int digito = 0;
        digito = ui.readInt("Digite el numero que corresponde a la operacion que desea\n1. Llenar arreglo\n2. Imprimir\n3. Sumar Pares\n4. Ordenar Valores\n5. Buscar Valor\n6. Obtener moda\n7. Salir");
        switch (digito) {
        case 1:
            llenar(vector, tamano);
            break;
        case 2:
            print(vector, tamano);
            break;
        case 3:
            sumar(vector, tamano);
            break;
        case 4:
            ordenar(vector, tamano);
            break;
        case 5:
            buscar(vector, tamano);
            break;
        case 6:
            moda(vector, tamano);
            break;
        case 7:
            return;
        default:
            break;
            ui.write("Digite un valor valido");
        }
    }
        
}
```

Comment: No parece que ese código tenga nada malo. ¿Puedes ser más claro? ¿Dónde se está llamando la librería? ¿Es un problema de compilación?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Simbolo externo sin resolver ¿Qué he hecho mal?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/65557/simbolo-externo-sin-resolver-qu%c3%a9-he-hecho-mal)